# How do I test if a variable is a number in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I just can't figure out how do I make sure an argument passed to my script is a number or not.

All I want to do is something like this:

```
test *isnumber* $1 && VAR=$1 || echo "need a number"
```

Any help?

Comment: As an aside -- the `test && echo "foo" && exit 0 || echo "bar" && exit 1` approach you're using may have some unintended side effects -- if the echo fails (perhaps output is to a closed FD), the `exit 0` will be skipped, and the code will then try to `echo "bar"`. If it fails at that too, the `&&` condition will fail, and it won't even execute `exit 1`! Using actual `if` statements rather than `&&`/`||` is less prone to unexpected side effects.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's the kind of really clever thinking that most people only get to when they have to track down hairy bugs...! I didn't ever think echo could return failure.

Comment: Bit late to the party, but I know about the dangers that Charles wrote about, as I had to go through them quite some time ago too.  So here's a 100% fool-proof (and well-readable) line for you:  `[[ $1 =~ "^[0-9]+$" ]] && { echo "number"; exit 0; } || { echo "not a number"; exit 1; }` The curly brackets indicate that things should NOT be executed in a subshell (which would definitely be that way with `()` parentheses used instead). Caveat: __Never miss the final semicolon__. Otherwise you might cause `bash` to print out the ugliest (and most pointless) error messages...

Comment: It doesn't work in Ubuntu, unless you don't remove the quotes. So it should just be `[[ 12345 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && echo OKKK || echo NOOO`

Comment: ...I removed the (faulty) answer from the question -- part of why answers should be separate is so they can be commented on, voted on, corrected, etc. individually.

Comment: You'll need to be **more specific** about what you mean by ***"number"***.  An integer?  A fixed-point number?  Scientific ("e") notation?  Is there a required range (e.g. a 64-bit unsigned value), or do you allow any number that can be written?

Comment: It's unbelievable that bash doesn't provide some reliable, built in way to validate whether or not a value is numeric.  The number, variety, and variation in quality of the answers here indicate that this is a serious problem.

Comment: Bash does provide a reliable means of determining if a number is an INTEGER. { VAR="asdfas" ; (( VAR )) ; echo $?; }  The equation will correctly fail if the answer is '0' because '0' is not an integer. I had the very same problem just a few minutes ago and found this thread with a quick serarch.  I hope this helps others.  Other people were close though.

Comment: @That one guy from the movie
Your code gives ugly messages on stderr. For instance `((5a))` gives `bash: ((: 5a: value too great for base (error token is "5a")`

Comment: @db-inf Easily fixed by redirecting stderr to null: `{ VAR="5e" ; (( VAR )) 2>/dev/null; echo $?; }`

Answer (score 1141, accepted):

One approach is to use a regular expression, like so:

```
re='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $yournumber =~ $re ]] ; then
   echo "error: Not a number" >&2; exit 1
fi
```

If the value is not necessarily an integer, consider amending the regex appropriately; for instance:

```
^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$
```

...or, to handle numbers with a sign:

```
^[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$
```

Comment: +1 for this approach, but take care with decimals, doing this test with, by example, "1.0" or "1,0" prints "error: Not a number".

Comment: @lhunath - true 'nuff. I tend to use it in more complex error handlers (ie. much more than just one "echo" following), but the habit leaked out here.

Comment: `^-*[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$` to also test for negative numbers

Comment: @Ben do you really want to handle more than one minus sign? I'd make it `^-?` rather than `^-*` unless you're actually doing the work to handle multiple inversions correctly.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting Makes all future output go to stderr. Not really a point to it here, where there's only one echo, but it's a habit I tend to get into for cases where error messages span multiple lines.

Comment: @Charles Duffy One could also consider the case of floats in the form .1234 without leading zero with `^[0-9]*([.][0-9]+)?$`  
This would require an additional check for a non-empty string tough..

Comment: With the full check then being `if ! [[ -n "$yournumber" && "$yournumber" =~ ^-?[0-9]*([.][0-9]+)?$ ]]; then
        echo NAN;
fi`

Comment: I'm not sure why the regular expression has to be saved in a variable, but if it's for the sake of compatibility I don't think it's necessary. You could just apply the expression directly: `[[ $yournumber =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]`.

Comment: @konsolebox yes, compatibility. Backslash handling in literal regular expressions on the right-hand side of `=~` changed between 3.1 and 3.2, whereas backslash handling in assignments is constant in all relevant releases of bash. Thus, following the practice of always assigning regular expressions to variables before matching against them using `=~` avoids surprises. I do it here to teach good habits, even though this particular regex has no backslash escapes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy And that's actually the reason why I'd prefer extended globbing over it which has been around since 2.05b or maybe earlier. `=~` started at 3.0 and has had varying implementations since then. What's actually most difficult in it is that you would still need to quote characters in values of variables you intended to provide as literal (e.g. `${VAR//./\\.}`) to prevent them from being parsed as regex characters whereas with `==` you could just place them in `""` e.g. `+(x)"$V"`. And the only reason why I could use it over ext. patterns is when I could make use of `BASH_REMATCH`.

Comment: @konsolebox With respect to the "most difficult" part, there are other ways to handle that problem. `[[ $s =~ $re_start"$literal"$re_end ]]`, for instance, treats the expanded contents of `"$literal"` as, well, literal, no escaping needed. (I also find `[.]` considerably more readable and otherwise easier to handle than `\.`, but that's admittedly bikeshedding)

Comment: @konsolebox ...by the way, I'm not arguing that there's only one right answer here. I've upvoted jilles' answer as well (though it needs the acknowledged bit of extension to be complete).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `[[ $s =~ $re_start"$literal"$re_end ]]` would work just like the way of `==` starting 3.2, but not on 3.0 or 3.1. `[[ $s =~ (x) ]]` without needing to save on a variable would also only work starting 4.0. Extended patterns need only to be enabled once at the start of the script so it wouldn't really matter. It's also compatible to all versions of bash starting 2.05b at least. Well these last comments of mine were already just about why someone would prefer extended patterns over `=~`. The info could also be helpful to other readers as well perhaps if they care compatibility.

Comment: @Hans then you're trying to use it with a shell that isn't bash 3.x or newer. Note that `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh (or, on ancient systems, Bourne shell), not bash, even when it's a symlink to bash.

Comment: I did `if [[ 123 =~ '^[0-9]+$' ]]; then echo good; fi` and got nothing. But `re='^[0-9]+$';  if [[ 123 =~ $re ]]; then echo good; fi` said `good`. Why? Do I have to escape something in the first version?

Comment: @FrozenFlame, putting the right-hand side of `=~` in quotes makes it no longer a regular expression but a regular string (in modern versions of bash but not some ancient ones), whereas the version I gave in this answer works consistently in every release where `=~` is supported at all.

Comment: What about when a number starts with a decimal point, e.g. `.5`? I would use `^-?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+$` instead.

Comment: Why the "!",  "=~"  and "[[ ]]"? Can someone explain the if/else components?

Comment: @LP_640, they're not if components -- you could use all those constructs outside the context of an `if`. See BashFAQ #31 (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for the rest; beyond what's covered there, `!` inverts the exit status of a command (make truthy things falsey, and falsey things true); it's a common way of spelling "not" in many, many languages.

Comment: @JMS, see `str="hello world"; re='[[:space:]]'; if [[ $str =~ $re ]]; then echo "matched"; fi` behaving as-expected at https://ideone.com/K7kM6M

Comment: @JMS, ...I wonder if your execution environment involves `eval` or some other pre-execution stage. Can you come up with an example that doesn't work without the quotes and post a link to it executing on http://ideone.com/?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy   dug into it a little more and you are right works either way.  not sure what was going on earlier.  Thank you for your comments.  removed my other comments.    btw.. couldn't get ideone.com to accept input.  is that a thing?

Comment: The only thing that's tricky (for me) about ideone's stdin implementation is that they don't implement the trailing newline required for valid UNIX text files, but rather go the DOS/Windows route of only putting newlines *between* lines but not after the last one, so `read` fails for the last line entered into the stdin box (which can be cured by putting an empty line on the end of the stdin box). Other than that, though, I haven't historically had a problem.

Comment: Be aware for the decimal starting with a dot like `.3`, or ending with a dot like `3.`, it will NOT work. I would like to suggest using `^[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?([0-9]+)?$`, however, three special cases: `.`, `+.`, `-.` have to be excluded first.

Comment: I was trying to accommodate for leading and trailing spaces, as in x=" 123 ".  So I tried changing re='^\s*[0-9]+\s*$' . But it never matches a number with lead and/or trailing spaces ...

Comment: it seems to work to not quote it if you don't want to declare a re variable: if [[ "123a" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then echo true ; else echo false ; fi

Comment: @AmanicA, it needs to be unquoted on the right hand side whether or not it comes from a variable. The use of variables as a recommended practice is for backwards compatibility with old versions of bash in cases where your regex contains backslashes, as described in the comment thread above.

Comment: As I'm very new to bash I wonder if there is any specific reason why the if statement in the first example can't be like this `if [[ ! $yournumber =~ $re ]]` ?

Comment: @MarcoDufal, maybe it's just because I haven't had my coffee yet, but how's that different from what _is_ already there?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy oh well simply the negation operator `!` is not in the square brackets in your code snippet.

Comment: Gotcha. Both perfectly legal; I like keeping the negation in the outer scope where doing so reflects the meaning as a matter of habit so more complex conditions are easier to read. For example, consider `[[ ! $foo && $bar ]]`; a reader needs to think about whether the `!` is applied only to `$foo`, or to the result of ANDing both; put it in the outside, and it's obvious at a glance that the negation applies to the entire test, not just one branch of it.

Comment: Or, to handle integers that do not have a lead zero `^[1-9][0-9]*$`

Comment: This is why i use python when its an option.

Comment: Shouldn't we use `return` instead of `exit 1`, which exits the ssh session as well

Comment: @alper, depends on the context. I was assuming this would be used in a script expected to exit if given invalid arguments. If you're using it on a function, yes, use `return`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Please have a look at my [fully edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61835747/1765658) (There is a more suitable floating version of regex solution)

Comment: I heard `printf` is MUCH MORE efficient.

Comment: @B.Shea, I'd need more context (what specific use of printf? Compared to what?) to even start to evaluate that. Many of the answers here pipe output of `printf` to something else; setting up a pipeline is not efficient at all.

Answer (score 404):

Without bashisms (works even in the System V sh),

```
case $string in
    ''|*[!0-9]*) echo bad ;;
    *) echo good ;;
esac
```

This rejects empty strings and strings containing non-digits, accepting everything else.

Negative or floating-point numbers need some additional work. An idea is to exclude `-` / `.` in the first "bad" pattern and add more "bad" patterns containing the inappropriate uses of them (`?*-*` / `*.*.*`)

Comment: +1 -- this is idiomatic, portable way back to the original Bourne shell, and has built-in support for glob-style wildcards.  If you come from another programming language, it looks eerie, but it's much more elegant than coping with the brittleness of various quoting issues and endless backwards/sideways compatibility problems with `if test ...`

Comment: You can change the first line to `${string#-}` (which doesn't work in antique Bourne shells, but works in any POSIX shell) to accept negative integers.

Comment: Also, this is easy to extend to floats -- just add `'.' | *.*.*` to the disallowed patterns, and add dot to the allowed characters. Similarly, you can allow an optional sign before, although then I would prefer `case ${string#[-+]}` to simply ignore the sign.

Comment: See this for handling signed integers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18620446/2013911

Comment: Shouldn't it be `case "$string" in` instead of `case $string in` ?

Comment: @Dor The quotes are not needed, since the case command does not perform word splitting and pathname generation on that word anyway. (However, expansions in case patterns may need quoting since it determines whether pattern matching characters are literal or special.)

Comment: Explanation for the pipe(vertical bar) character:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85939/what-is-the-pipe-character-xy-in-the-case-statement

Comment: This seem to be the quickest way! Have a look at [my comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61835747/1765658)

Answer (score 264):

The following solution can also be used in basic shells such as Bourne without the need for regular expressions.  Basically any numeric value evaluation operations using non-numbers will result in an error which will be implicitly considered as false in shell:

```
"$var" -eq "$var"
```

as in:

```
#!/bin/bash

var=a

if [ -n "$var" ] && [ "$var" -eq "$var" ] 2>/dev/null; then
  echo number
else
  echo not a number
fi
```

You can can also test for $? the return code of the operation which is more explicit:

```
[ -n "$var" ] && [ "$var" -eq "$var" ] 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   echo $var is not number
fi
```

Redirection of standard error is there to hide the "integer expression expected" message that bash prints out in case we do not have a number.

**CAVEATS** (thanks to the comments below):

- Numbers with decimal points are *not* identified as valid "numbers"
- Using `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]` will always evaluate to `true`
- Most non-Bash shells will always evaluate this expression as `true`
- The behavior in Bash is undocumented and may therefore change without warning
- If the value includes spaces after the number (e.g. "1 a") produces error, like `bash: [[: 1 a: syntax error in expression (error token is "a")`
- If the value is the same as var-name (e.g. i="i"), produces error, like `bash: [[: i: expression recursion level exceeded (error token is "i")`

Comment: I'd still recommend this (but with the variables quoted to allow for empty strings), since the result is guaranteed to be *usable* as a number in Bash, no matter what.

Comment: Take care to use single brackets; `[[ a -eq a ]]` evaluates to true (both arguments get converted to zero)

Comment: This is indeed very neat and works in `bash` (which was requested) and most other shells, but sadly not in `ksh`. If you want to be portable, use jilles' solution.

Comment: Very nice! Note this this only works for an integer, not any number. I needed to check for a single argument which must be an integer, so this worked well: `if ! [ $# -eq 1 -o "$1" -eq "$1" ] 2>/dev/null; then`

Comment: I would strongly advise against this method because of the not insignificant number of shells whose `[` builtin will evaluate the arguments as arithmetic. That is true in both ksh93 and mksh. Further, since both of those support arrays, there is easy opportunity for code injection. Use a pattern match instead.

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni, in current releases of bash, these values are interpreted with numeric-context rules only for `[[ ]]` but not for `[ ]`. That said, this behavior is unspecified by both the POSIX standard for `test` and in bash's own documentation; future versions of bash could modify behavior to match ksh without breaking any documented behavioral promises, so relying on its current behavior persisting is not guaranteed to be safe.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for explanation. I wasn't really worrying about that 7 years ago when I wrote this :D

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not entirely "undocumented". `man test` shows `-eq` is for ints and `=` is for strings. the man page *implies* but doesn't explicitly say `-eq` will fail for string comparison.

Comment: How can you negate this?

Comment: @pfnuesel `! [ "$var" -eq "$var" ]`.   Reason: `-ne` returns non-zero for non-integer arguments.

Comment: You'll need to test that `$var` is non-null. I'll suggest an edit:

`[ -n "$var" ] && [ "$var" -eq "$var" ] 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @TomHale and Alberto, *${x:-1} -eq ${x:-0}* protects against empty input.

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni You really should modify your answer to clearly state that it only works for **integers**, i.e. change all mentions of "number" by "integer". I know you hinted it in your caveat section, but you're using the general word "number" everywhere in the main part of your message which is false from a mathematical (set theory) point of view and misleads the inexperienced user.

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni @CharlesDuffy ... why should this not be POSIX compliant? When using the `[ … ]` form (which is `test`) POSIX quite clearly states that this is:
"n1 -eq  n2: True if the integers n1 and n2 are algebraically equal; otherwise, false."
(https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)
Strings cannot be integers or algebraically equal, so the worst than can happen is that it gives an exit status `>1` instead of just `1` which is however not an issue for the above problem.

Comment: @calestyo, the standard you quote doesn't say anything about how hard a shell should (or shouldn't) try to coerce a non-integer value into an integer. Some shells, given a string, will try to coerce it to an integer by doing things like looking at whether it is in fact the name of a variable that contains an integer; and those going-to-extra-lengths approaches can sometimes involve code execution. Even those shells that don't process anything but a proper integer will often have side effects when non-integers are present, such as writing an error message to stderr.

Comment: @calestyo, ...which is to say: The standard you quote says what the shell _must_ do to be compliant, but it doesn't by any means proscribe the shell from doing other things in addition. That's true for most of POSIX: Unspecified behaviors are room for extensions, as opposed to being prohibited by default.

Comment: @TomHale - May I ask why we need to test `[ -n "$var" ]`? `v='' ; [ "$v" -eq "$v" ]` returns false (return code = 2).

Comment: This solution is POSIX compliant, nice and concise. But do note that it fails for overflow numbers, `v=99999999999999999999999999999 ; [ "$v" -eq "$v" ] 2> /dev/null ; echo $?` prints 2. On the other hand, `v=999999999999999999999999999999 ; expr 1 + "$v" \* "$v" 2> /dev/null ; echo $?` works well and prints 0. Which one is better depends if you need to check if it is within the integer range.

Comment: ((mvar+0 > 0)) && echo num || echo alpha is more readable if you expext a positive integer other than 0

Answer (score 83):

Nobody suggested bash's [extended pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
[[ $1 == ?(-)+([0-9]) ]] && echo "$1 is an integer"
```

or using [a POSIX character class](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-13):

```
[[ $1 == ?(-)+([[:digit:]]) ]] && echo "$1 is an integer"
```

Comment: Glenn, I remove `shopt -s extglob` from your post (that I upvoted, it's one of my favorite answers here), since in [Conditional Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) you can read: _When the `==` and `!=` operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in [Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching), as if the `extglob` shell option were enabled._ I hope you don't mind!

Comment: In such contexts, you don't need to `shopt extglob`... that's a good thing to know!

Comment: Works well for simple integers.

Comment: Your solution does not work In `3.2.25(1)-release` of bash: `-bash: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `('
-bash: syntax error near `?(-'. In that release, the featured noted by @gniourf_gniourf is not working.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, unlike **extended pattern matching** does not work in 3.2.25 release as you quoted, the **simple pattern matching** does work, for instance, `[[ x3x = *[[:digit:]]* ]]`, even with the single `=` operator. In 3.2 bash man pages the string *`as if the extglob shell option were enabled`* is not found.

Comment: @Jdamian: you're right, this was added in Bash 4.1 (which was released at the end of 2009… Bash 3.2 was released in 2006… it's now an antique software, sorry for those who are stuck in the past). Also, you could argue that extglobs where introduced in version 2.02 (released in 1998), and don't work in <2.02 versions… Now your comment here will serve as a caveat regarding older versions.

Comment: Answer would be stronger if it gave a little more explanation.

Comment: @glennjackman: How to avoid negative numbers using the approach you are using ? I want only positive numbers.

Comment: @Destructor, remove the `?(-)` bit that optionally matches the leading hyphen, so you just match digits with `+([0-9])`

Comment: This worked for me in `bash 5.0.11`, but shouldn't it be `"$1"` instead of `$1`? or doesn't matter in this case?

Comment: Variables within `[[...]]` are not subject to word splitting or glob expansion.

Comment: also my favorite answer, I feel that more explaining will be nice; also seems that it is not both hands
[[ $1 == ?(-)+([0-9]) ]] --> does work
[[ ?(-)+([0-9]) == $1 ]] --> did not work (for me at least, ubuntu 18)

Comment: @ThiagoConrado, look up [`[[...]]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b) in the manual (or `help [[` at a bash prompt): only the right-hand side of `==` is a pattern.

Comment: How would you reverse this to check for non-integer?

Comment: Use `[[:digit:]]` instead of `[:digit:]` for POSIX.

Comment: Just a comment... unfortunately in zsh this doesn't work.

Comment: @Bernardo, which "this" is this? Are you commenting on my answer or one of the other comments? Perhaps it's the bug in the answer that bugi pointed out (now fixed)

Comment: @glennjackman "this is" is the code in your answer. I'm commenting about your answer.  I've tested with #bugi approach about POSIX too, also doesn't work. But pay attention, I didn't report a bug, I just write a comment.

Comment: I can confirm the answer doesn't work in zsh: `syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Did you read my [Performance comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61835747/1765658)?  Using *`regex`* for this is something overkill.

Answer (score 75):

## Some performance and compatibility hints

There are some strongly different methods regarding different kinds of tests.

I reviewed most relevant methods and built this comparison.
Mostly:

- [Charles Duffy's answer, based on bash *regex*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/806923/1765658),
- [jilles's answer based on `case` switches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3951175/1765658),
- [glenn jackman's answer based on bash *parameter expansion*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13089269/1765658) and
- [Alberto Zaccagni's answer based of interger capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/808740/1765658).

### Unsigned Integer `is_uint()`

These functions implement code to assess whether an expression is an unsigned integer, i.e. consists entirely of digits.

- Using ***parameter expansion***

  ([glenn jackman's answer based on bash *parameter expansion*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13089269/1765658). This was my approach before all this!)

  ```
  isuint_Parm() { [ "$1" ] && [ -z "${1//[0-9]}" ] ;}
  ```
- Using ***fork to `grep`***

  Proposed by [Sergio Abreu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16374912/1765658)

  ```
  isuint_Grep() { grep -qE '^[0-9]+$' <<<"$1"; }
  ```

  I test this method only once because it's very slow. This is just there to show what not to do.
- Using ***[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) integer capabilities***

  ```
  isuint_Bash() { (( 10#$1 >= 0 )) 2>/dev/null ;}
  ```

  or even:

  ```
  isuint_Bash() { set -- "${1//[+-]/.}";(( 10#$1 >= 0 )) 2>/dev/null ;}
  ```

  But **don't use this!!!** Thanks to [gniourf_gniourf's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) for driving me to this!
- Using ***`case`***

  [jilles's answer based on `case` switches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3951175/1765658)

  ```
  isuint_Case() { case $1 in ''|*[!0-9]*) return 1;;esac;}
  ```
- Using ***[bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s regex***

  [Charles Duffy's answer, based on bash *regex*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/806923/1765658)

  ```
  isuint_Regx() { [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ;}
  ```

### Signed integer `is_int()`

These functions implement code to assess whether an expression is a signed integer, i.e. as above but permitting an optional sign before the number.

- Using ***parameter expansion***

  ```
  isint_Parm() { local chk=${1#[+-]}; [ "$chk" ] && [ -z "${chk//[0-9]}" ] ;}
  ```
- Using ***[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) integer capabilities***

  Something like [Alberto Zaccagni's answer based on *integer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/808740/1765658):

  ```
  isint_Shell() {  [ -n "$1" ] && [ "$1" -eq "$1" ] 2>/dev/null;}
  ```

  Or using *bashisms*:

  ```
  isint_Bash() {  set -- "${1//[!+-]}" ${1#${1//[!+-]}};
                  (( ( 0 ${1:-+} 10#$2 ) ? 1:1 )) 2>/dev/null ;}
  ```
- Using ***`case`***

  ```
  isint_Case() { case ${1#[-+]} in ''|*[!0-9]*) return 1;;esac;}
  ```
- Using ***[bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s regex***

  ```
  isint_Regx() { [[ $1 =~ ^[+-]?[0-9]+$ ]] ;}
  ```

### Number (unsigned float) `is_num()`

These functions implement code to assess whether an expression is a floating-point number, i.e. as above but permitting an optional decimal point and additional digits after it.  This does not attempt to cover numeric expressions in scientific notation (e.g. 1.0234E-12).

- Using ***parameter expansion***

  ```
  isnum_Parm() { local ck=${1#[+-]};ck=${ck/.};[ "$ck" ]&&[ -z "${ck//[0-9]}" ];}
  ```
- Using ***[bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s regex***

  ```
  isnum_Regx() { [[ $1 =~ ^[+-]?([0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)$ ]] ;}
  ```
- Using ***`case`***

  ```
  isnum_Case() { case ${1#[-+]} in ''|.|*[!0-9.]*|*.*.*) return 1;; esac ;}
  ```

### Tests of concepts

(You could copy/paste this test code after previous declared functions.)

```
testcases=(
    0  1 42 -3 +42 +3. .9 3.14 +3.141 -31.4 '' . 3-3 3.1.4 3a a3 blah 'Good day!'
);printf '%-12s %4s %4s %4s %4s %4s %4s %4s %4s %4s %4s %4s %4s %4s\n' \
    Value\\Func U{Prm,Grp,Bsh,Cse,Rgx} I{Prm,Shl,Bsh,Cse,Rgx} N{Prm,Cse,Rgx};\
for var in "${testcases[@]}";do
    outstr='';
    for func in isuint_{Parm,Grep,Bash,Case,Regx} \
          isint_{Parm,Shell,Bash,Case,Regx} isnum_{Parm,Case,Regx};do
        if $func "$var"; then
            outstr+='   ##'
        else
            outstr+='   --'
        fi
    done
    printf '%-11s %s\n' "$var" "$outstr"
done
```

Should output:

```
Value\Func   UPrm UGrp UBsh UCse URgx IPrm IShl IBsh ICse IRgx NPrm NCse NRgx
0              ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##
1              ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##
42             ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##
-3             --   --   --   --   --   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##
+42            --   --   --   --   --   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##
+3.            --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   ##   ##   ##
.9             --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   ##   ##   ##
3.14           --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   ##   ##   ##
+3.141         --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   ##   ##   ##
-31.4          --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   ##   ##   ##
               --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --
.              --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --
3-3            --   --   --   --   --   --   --   ##   --   --   --   --   --
3.1.4          --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --
3a             --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --
a3             --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --
blah           --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --
Good day!      --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   --
```

I hope!

**Note: `uint_bash` seems not perfect!** In fine: [second gniourf_gniourf's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash/61835747?noredirect=1#comment137316885_61835747) rightly said:

> All methods using arithmetic context are subject to arbitrary code injection and are very dangerous! All the *_Bash functions here are dangerous and should be marked as ANTI=PATTERNS and "DANGEROUS: SUBJECT TO ARBITRARY CODE INJECTION. SHOULD NOT BE USED UNDER ANY CIRCUMPSTANCES".

### Performance comparison

Then I've built this test function:

```
testFunc() {
    local tests=1000 start=${EPOCHREALTIME//.}
    for ((;tests--;)) ;do
        "$1" "$3"
    done
    printf -v "$2" %u $((${EPOCHREALTIME//.}-start))
}
percent(){ local p=00$((${1}00000/$2));printf -v "$3" %.2f%% ${p::-3}.${p: -3};}
sortedTests() {
    local func NaNTime NumTime ftyp="$1" nTest="$2" tTest="$3" min i pct line
    local -a order=()
    shift 3
    for func ;do
        testFunc "${ftyp}_$func" NaNTime "$tTest"
        testFunc "${ftyp}_$func" NumTime "$nTest"
        order[NaNTime+NumTime]=${ftyp}_$func\ $NumTime\ $NaNTime
    done
    printf '%-12s %11s %11s %14s\n' Function Number NaN Total
    min="${!order[*]}" min=${min%% *}
    for i in "${!order[@]}";do
        read -ra line <<<"${order[i]}"
        percent "$i" "$min" pct
        printf '%-12s %9d\U00B5s %9d\U00B5s  %12d\U00B5s  %9s\n' \
               "${line[@]}" "$i" "$pct"
    done
}
```

I could run in this way:

```
sortedTests isuint "This is not a number." 31415926535897932384 \
            Case Grep Parm Bash Regx ;\
sortedTests isint  "This is not a number." 31415926535897932384 \
            Case Parm Shell Bash Regx ;\
sortedTests isnum "This string is clearly not a number..." \
            3.141592653589793238462643383279502884  Case Parm Regx
```

On my host, this shows somthing like:

```
Function          Number         NaN          Total
isuint_Case       1763µs      1535µs          3298µs    100.00%
isuint_Parm       2571µs      3319µs          5890µs    178.59%
isuint_Regx       5014µs      5952µs         10966µs    332.50%
isuint_Bash       6379µs      6106µs         12485µs    378.56%
isuint_Grep     293347µs    287733µs        581080µs  17619.16%

Function          Number         NaN          Total
isint_Case        2020µs      1938µs          3958µs    100.00%
isint_Parm        3291µs      4707µs          7998µs    202.07%
isint_Shell       5775µs      5183µs         10958µs    276.86%
isint_Regx        5371µs      5836µs         11207µs    283.15%
isint_Bash        8946µs      7718µs         16664µs    421.02%

Function          Number         NaN          Total
isnum_Case        2181µs      2232µs          4413µs    100.00%
isnum_Parm        4502µs      6017µs         10519µs    238.36%
isnum_Regx        8247µs     13019µs         21266µs    481.89%
```

You could download the [full isnum comparison script here](https://www.f-hauri.ch/vrac/isnum_comparission.sh) or the [full isnum comparison script as text here](https://www.f-hauri.ch/vrac/isnum_comparission.sh.txt) (with UTF8 and LATIN handling).

## Conclusion

- The `case` way is clearly the quickest! About 3x quicker than  *regex* and 2x quicker than using *parameter expansion*.
- ***forks*** (to `grep` or any binaries) should be avoided when not needed, mostly for small strings, a single line, or other *one shot* operations.

**The `case` method has become my favored choice:**

```
is_uint() { case $1        in '' | *[!0-9]*              ) return 1;; esac ;}
is_int()  { case ${1#[-+]} in '' | *[!0-9]*              ) return 1;; esac ;}
is_unum() { case $1        in '' | . | *[!0-9.]* | *.*.* ) return 1;; esac ;}
is_num()  { case ${1#[-+]} in '' | . | *[!0-9.]* | *.*.* ) return 1;; esac ;}
```

### About compatibility

For this, I wrote a [little test script based on previous tests](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/isnum_test.sh.txt), with:

```
for shell in bash dash 'busybox sh' ksh zsh "$@";do
    printf "%-12s  " "${shell%% *}"
    $shell < <(testScript) 2>&1 | xargs
done
```

This shows:

```
bash          Success
dash          Success
busybox       Success
ksh           Success
zsh           Success
```

As I know other [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) based solution like ***regex*** and ***[bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s integer*** won't work in many other shells and ***forks*** are resource expensive, I would prefer the *`case`* way
(just before ***parameter expansion*** which is mostly compatible too).

Comment: I agree, anyway, I prefer not to use regex, when I could use parameter expansion... Abusing of RE will make bash script slower

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, On my raspberry pi, 1000 iteration will take 2,5sec with my version and 4,4sec with your version!

Comment: Can't argue with that. 

Comment: TIL `set --` can be used to set positional params

Comment: @tripleee The script you point is buggy!  `casenum` don't work with floating numbers! And his test don't use his `$fun` variable!! But I agree, I could pay some attention to this way of doing!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; updated the snippet. Sorry for the silly typo. The `case` case (sic) is now clearly faster on IdeOne too. (I should have checked ...) Though probably a better test would not only check the success flow.

Comment: Already working on: `isnum(){ case ${1#[-+]} in ''|*[!0-9.]*|*.*.*) return -1;;esac ;}`... seem good!

Comment: This script could be found there: [isnum_comparission.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/isnum_comparission.sh.txt)

Comment: Perhaps notice that `isuint_Bash` is slightly faster than `case` in the `NaN` test. If you are in a tight loop where every cycle counts, and you expect mostly invalid input, that could tilt the comparison in favor of the parameter expansion version. But only for the `uint` case. Perhaps the difference is small enough that it's within the margin of measurement error anyway.

Comment: @tripleee I don't thik. This look a tiny difference due to the fact tests was done on my personal desk, who's not quiet. Running this test (from [my script](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/isnum_comparission.sh)) many times will present this difference randomly in the other way.,,

Comment: @tripleee redo the test like published there, many time when my desk was relatively quiet, then chosed more relevant output to publish there. (Did you try my script? I've added a `+Numberr` column, I won't try to explain this there;)

Comment: Based on these solutions, you could expand to full float comparisions which would include scientific notations: `is_float() { is_num "${1/[eE][-+]/}"; }`

Comment: First downgrade! I'm curious knowing why!!

Comment: Be careful, the "Bash" cases are broken: you're litteraly using user input as code, and this is always bad! Try it, e.g., with the data `1 && 1`, or more evil: `1 && a[$(touch I_JUST_TOUCHED_A_FILE_LOL)]`. Please remove this antipattern from your answer!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Just tried: `data='1 && a[$(touch I_JUST_TOUCHED_A_FILE_LOL)]';case $data in JOB ) echo job;; *JUST* ) echo tout juste;;*) echo other;;esac;` don't see any kind of problem! ... ( `case` != `eval` :-)

Comment: the problem comes in the arithmetic context: `isuint_Bash() { (( 10#$1 >= 0 )) 2>/dev/null ;}` and then `isuint_Bash '1 && 1' && echo "Is a number"'` so according to this, `1 && 1` is a number, and worse: `isuint_Bash '1 && a[$(touch I_JUST_TOUCHED_A_FILE_LOL)]' && echo "Is a number"` will say it's a number and touch a file :(

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Bravo! I've edited my answer to point to your comment! But **this is not `case` method** it is a ***bash integer*** method!! The case method, with 4 test functions at bottom of this answer are really robusts and notably quicker the using *regex*.

Comment: I agree that the `case` method is very good! just wanted to point out the code injection issue when using the arithmetic context method. All your methods using arithmetic context are subject to arbitrary code injection and are very dangerous! all the `*_Bash` functions you gave are dangerous and should be marked as [ANTI-PATTERNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) and "DANGEROUS: SUBJECT TO ARBITRARY CODE INJECTION. SHOULD NOT BE USED UNDER ANY CIRCUMPSTANCES". Please do another edit to clearly mention this security issue for all the `_Bash` functions!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Answer edited again! (Just copy the more relevant of your comment) Thanks for driving me to this! (Not well tested as they don't show interesting perfs, but you do! Thanks again.)

Answer (score 57):

This tests if a number is a non-negative integer. It is shell independent (i.e. without bashisms) and uses only shell built-ins:

```
[ ! -z "${num##*[!0-9]*}" ] && echo "is a number" || echo "is not a number";
```

---

A previous version of this answer proposed:

```
[ -z "${num##[0-9]*}" ] && echo "is a number" || echo "is not a number";
```

but this is **INCORRECT** since it accepts any string starting with a digit, as [jilles suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash/2704760#comment4220661_2704760).

Comment: This does not work properly, it accepts any string starting with a digit. Note that WORD in ${VAR##WORD} and similar is a shell pattern, not a regular expression.

Comment: Can you translate that expression into English, please? I really want to use it, but I don't understand it enough to trust it, even after perusing the bash man page.

Comment: `*[!0-9]*` is a pattern that matches all strings with at least 1 non-digit character.
`${num##*[!0-9]*}` is a "parameter expansion" where we take the content of the `num` variable and remove the longest string that matches the pattern.
If the result of the parameter expansion is not empty (`! [ -z ${...} ]`) then it's a number since it does not contain any non-digit character.

Comment: Unfortunately this fails if there any digits in the argument, even if it is not valid number. For example "exam1ple" or "a2b".

Comment: Both fail with `122s` `:-(`

Comment: But that's good, because "exam1ple", "a2b" and "122s" are all not numbers.

Answer (score 27):

I'm surprised at the solutions directly parsing number formats in shell.
shell is not well suited to this, being a DSL for controlling files and processes.
There are ample number parsers a little lower down, for example:

```
isdecimal() {
  # filter octal/hex/ord()
  num=$(printf '%s' "$1" | sed "s/^0*\([1-9]\)/\1/; s/'/^/")

  test "$num" && printf '%f' "$num" >/dev/null 2>&1
}
```

Change '%f' to whatever particular format you require.

Comment: `isnumber(){ printf '%f' "$1" &>/dev/null && echo "this is a number" || echo "not a number"; }`

Comment: Nice solution.  printf really works well, even errors with something appropriate-ish.

Comment: @sputnick your version breaks the inherent (and useful) return value semantics of the original function. So, instead, simply leave the function as-is, and use it: `isnumber 23 && echo "this is a number" || echo "not a number"`

Comment: Shouldn't this have also `2>/dev/null`, so that `isnumber "foo"` does not pollute stderr?

Comment: To call modern shells like bash "a DSL for controlling files and processes" is ignoring that they're used for much more than that - some distros have built entire package managers and web interfaces on it (as ugly as that might be). Batch files fit your description though, as even setting a variable there is difficult.

Comment: It's funny that you're trying to be smart by copying some idioms from other languages. Unfortunately this doesn't work in shells. Shells are very special, and without solid knowledge about them, you're likely to write broken code. Your code is broken: `isnumber "'a"` will return true. This is documented in the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) where you'll read: _If the leading character is a single-quote or double-quote, the value shall be the numeric value in the underlying codeset of the character following the single-quote or double-quote._

Comment: There are very likely other cases where your code will break. I just gave one. I hope that the 27 guys who upvoted didn't use this in critical production code. `:D`.

Comment: Another case where it fails: `isinteger() { [[ $1 ]] && printf '%d' "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1; }` will fail with, e.g., `isinteger 09`: that's because of a silly leading `0`. Now you might argue that `09` shouldn't be validated... whatever, `isnumber "'a"` is an already good proof that all this design is broken.

Comment: Note the function was isnumber(). If you want a more restrictive isdecimal() then you could filter with `sed "s/^0*//; s/'/^/"`

Comment: I know the function was `isnumber` (the `isinteger` function I gave is just a (failed) attempt in generalizing your method). Funny, but now `0` is not a number. Your function now spawns 4 subshells, uses an external command, doesn't work. And you claim that a shell is just a DSL for controlling files and processes? you need to learn better shell techniques, and when you're more knowledgeable you'll see that the only sane way of solving this problem is to indeed parse the string.

Comment: By the way, you're misusing `printf`. For example, your function validates `42\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n` or `%s42%s` or `%d9`

Comment: Much better! yet it still validates variables that contain trailing newlines: `$'1\n\n\n'`; that's because `$(...)` trims trailing newlines. Whatever. You're at the point where you criticize methods that parse the string explicitly (and so we expect your method to be really superior) yet: your method spawns 3 subshells, isn't even 100% safe (regarding trailling newlines), somehow parses the string with `sed`, is much less efficient than methods that directly parse the string. Good job.

Comment: Could you add an example of how to call this and use its result?

Comment: "There are ample number parsers a little lower down" -- yet you're not using one, but implementing your own regex-based solution. Since bash has native regexes, this buys what exactly?

Comment: @pixelbeat I have real trouble understanding the rationale behind and use of  `s/'/^/`. Would you mind precising it ? I don't see how replacing `'` with `^` would make any sense (this is what `sed` does when `^` is alone) when considering a decimal input number.

Comment: Replacing ' with ^, is replacing something printf interprets as a number with something it does not. I.e. We generally don't want to  consider `'blah` as a number, so tweak it to something that printf will reject

Comment: Why is it correct to treat `'10` as a number either? `'`s can legitimately be present as _syntax_ in code that encodes literals meant to be treated as numbers, but they should never be present in the data.

Answer (score 22):

I was looking at the answers and...
realized that nobody thought about FLOAT numbers (with dot)!

Using grep is great too.
-E means extended regexp
-q means quiet (doesn't echo)
-qE is the combination of both.

To test directly in the command line:

```
$ echo "32" | grep -E ^\-?[0-9]?\.?[0-9]+$  
# answer is: 32

$ echo "3a2" | grep -E ^\-?[0-9]?\.?[0-9]+$  
# answer is empty (false)

$ echo ".5" | grep -E ^\-?[0-9]?\.?[0-9]+$  
# answer .5

$ echo "3.2" | grep -E ^\-?[0-9]?\.?[0-9]+$  
# answer is 3.2
```

Using in a bash script:

```
check=`echo "$1" | grep -E ^\-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$`

if [ "$check" != '' ]; then    
  # it IS numeric
  echo "Yeap!"
else
  # it is NOT numeric.
  echo "nooop"
fi
```

To match JUST integers, use this:

```
# change check line to:
check=`echo "$1" | grep -E ^\-?[0-9]+$`
```

Comment: The solutions using awk by triple_r and tripleee work with floats.

Comment: Thanks for this and very good point! Cause the question is actually how to check if it is a *number* and not just an integer.

Comment: I thank you too Tanasis! Let's help each other always.

Answer (score 14):

Just a follow up to @mary. But because I don't have enough rep, couldn't post this as a comment to that post. Anyways, here is what I used:

```
isnum() { awk -v a="$1" 'BEGIN {print (a == a + 0)}'; }
```

The function will return "1" if the argument is a number, otherwise will return "0". This works for integers as well as floats. Usage is something like:

```
n=-2.05e+07
res=`isnum "$n"`
if [ "$res" == "1" ]; then
     echo "$n is a number"
else
     echo "$n is not a number"
fi
```

Comment: Printing a number is less useful than setting an exit code. `'BEGIN { exit(1-(a==a+0)) }'` is slightly hard to grok but can be used in a function which returns true or false just like `[`, `grep -q`, etc.

Answer (score 11):

```
test -z "${i//[0-9]}" && echo digits || echo no no no
```

`${i//[0-9]}` replaces any digit in the value of `$i` with an empty string, see `man -P 'less +/parameter\/' bash`. `-z` checks if resulting string has zero length.

if you also want to exclude the case when `$i` is empty, you could use one of these constructions:

```
test -n "$i" && test -z "${i//[0-9]}" && echo digits || echo not a number
[[ -n "$i" && -z "${i//[0-9]}" ]] && echo digits || echo not a number
```

Comment: Thumbs up especially for the `man -P 'less +/parameter\/' bash` part. Learning something new every day. :)

Comment: @sjas You could easily add `\-` in regular expression to address the issue. Use `[0-9\-\.\+]` to account for floats and signed numbers.

Comment: @sjas ok, my fault

Comment: @sjas `echo $i | python -c $'import sys\ntry:\n float(sys.stdin.read().rstrip())\nexcept:\n sys.exit(1)' && echo yes || echo no`

Answer (score 11):

For my problem, I only needed to ensure that a user doesn't accidentally enter some text thus I tried to keep it simple and readable

```
isNumber() {
    (( $1 )) 2>/dev/null
}
```

According to the man page this pretty much does what I want

> If the value of the expression is non-zero, the return status is 0

To prevent nasty error messages for strings that "might be numbers" I ignore the error output

```
$ (( 2s ))
bash: ((: 2s: value too great for base (error token is "2s")
```

Comment: This is wrong (buggy)! Try this: `foo=1;set -- foo;(( $1 )) 2>/dev/null && echo "'$1' is a number"`

Answer (score 10):

Old question, but I just wanted to tack on my solution. This one doesn't require any strange shell tricks, or rely on something that hasn't been around forever.

```
if [ -n "$(printf '%s\n' "$var" | sed 's/[0-9]//g')" ]; then
    echo 'is not numeric'
else
    echo 'is numeric'
fi
```

Basically it just removes all digits from the input, and if you're left with a non-zero-length string then it wasn't a number.

Comment: This fails for an empty `var`.

Comment: Or for variables with trailing newlines or something like `$'0\n\n\n1\n\n\n2\n\n\n3\n'`.

Comment: Requiring *multiple* external processes for something the shell is perfectly capable of processing using pure builtins is just bad practice.

Answer (score 10):

This can be achieved by using `grep` to see if the variable in question matches an extended regular expression.

#### Test integer `1120`:

```
yournumber=1120
if echo "$yournumber" | grep -qE '^[0-9]+$'; then
    echo "Valid number."
else
    echo "Error: not a number."
fi
```

Output: `Valid number.`

#### Test non-integer `1120a`:

```
yournumber=1120a
if echo "$yournumber" | grep -qE '^[0-9]+$'; then
    echo "Valid number."
else
    echo "Error: not a number."
fi
```

Output: `Error: not a number.`

---

### Explanation

- The `grep`, the `-E` switch allows us to use extended regular expression `'^[0-9]+$'`. This regular expression means the variable should only `[]` contain the numbers `0-9` zero through nine from the `^` beginning to the `$` end of the variable and should have at least `+` one character.
- The `grep`, the `-q` quiet switch turns off any output whether or not it finds anything.
- `if` checks the exit status of `grep`. Exit status `0` means success and anything greater means an error. The `grep` command has an exit status of `0` if it finds a match and `1` when it doesn't;

So putting it all together, in the `if` test, we `echo` the variable `$yournumber` and `|` pipe it to `grep` which with the `-q` switch silently matches the `-E` extended regular expression `'^[0-9]+$'` expression. The exit status of `grep` will be `0` if `grep` successfully found a match and `1` if it didn't. If succeeded to match, we `echo "Valid number."`. If it failed to match, we `echo "Error: not a number."`.

---

### For Floats or Doubles

We can just change the regular expression from `'^[0-9]+$'` to `'^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$'` for floats or doubles.

#### Test float `1120.01`:

```
yournumber=1120.01
if echo "$yournumber" | grep -qE '^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$'; then
    echo "Valid number."
else
    echo "Error: not a number."
fi
```

Output: `Valid number.`

#### Test float `11.20.01`:

```
yournumber=11.20.01
if echo "$yournumber" | grep -qE '^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$'; then
    echo "Valid number."
else
    echo "Error: not a number."
fi
```

Output: `Error: not a number.`

---

### For Negatives

To allow negative integers, just change the regular expression from `'^[0-9]+$'` to `'^\-?[0-9]+$'`.

To allow negative floats or doubles, just change the regular expression from `'^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$'` to `'^\-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$'`.

Comment: LGTM; answer as-edited has my +1. The only things I'd do differently at this point are just matters of opinion rather than correctness (f/e, using `[-]` instead of `\-` and `[.]` instead of `\.` is a little more verbose, but it means your strings don't have to change if they're used in a context where backslashes get consumed).

Comment: I was using a different approach with `if [[ $yournumber =~ ^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]] ; then` in an old Ubuntu 14.04 based system but, somehow, it stopped working after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, your first solution for "Test Integer" does the same in 20.04. I can't say if it is related to the upgrade or maybe my script was wrong in first instance and -somehow- yet working in the old system. Thank you very much.

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo, perhaps might the script have been using `#!/bin/sh`? If so, it should still work in modern Ubuntu as long as you use a `#!/bin/bash` shebang, and avoid starting scripts with `sh scriptname` (which ignores the shebang and forces use of `sh` instead of `bash`).

Comment: Using an external process for something Bash has built in is always dubious.

Answer (score 7):

```
[[ $1 =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]] && echo "number"
```

Don't forget `-` to include negative numbers!

Comment: What is the minimum version of bash? I just get  bash: conditional binary operator expected
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `=~'

Comment: @PaulHargreaves `=~` existed at least as far back as bash 3.0.

Comment: @PaulHargreaves you probably had a problem with your first operand, e.g. too many quotation marks or similar

Comment: @JoshuaClayton I asked about the version because it's very *very* old bash on a Solaris 7 box, which we still have and it doesn't support =~

Answer (score 7):

I would try this:

```
printf "%g" "$var" &> /dev/null
if [[ $? == 0 ]] ; then
    echo "$var is a number."
else
    echo "$var is not a number."
fi
```

Note: this recognizes nan and inf as number.

Comment: either duplicate of, or perhaps better suited as a comment to, pixelbeat's answer (using `%f` is probably better anyway)

Comment: Instead of checking the previous status code, why not just put it in the `if` itself? That's what `if` does... `if printf "%g" "$var" &> /dev/null; then ...`

Comment: This has other caveats. It will validate the empty string, and strings like `'a`.

Comment: Best solution, in my book. I tried bc before realising bc doesn't do floats.

The interpretation of the empty string as a number  is a minor caveat (and "a" is not interpreted as a number).

Comment: @JPGConnly, what do you mean "bc doesn't do floats"?

Comment: See [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 7):

A clear answer has already been given by @charles Dufy and others.
A pure bash solution would be using the following :

```
string="-12,345"
if [[ "$string" =~ ^-?[0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]*$ ]]
then
    echo $string is a number
else
    echo $string is not a number
fi
```

Although for real numbers it is not mandatory to have a number before the [radix point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_point).

To provide a more thorough support of floating numbers and scientific notation (many programs in C/Fortran or else will export float this way), a useful addition to this line would be the following :

```
string="1.2345E-67"
if [[ "$string" =~ ^-?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]*[eE]?-?[0-9]+$ ]]
then
    echo $string is a number
else
    echo $string is not a number
fi
```

Thus leading to a way to differentiate types of number, if you are looking for any specific type :

```
string="-12,345"
if [[ "$string" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]
then
    echo $string is an integer
elif [[ "$string" =~ ^-?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]*$ ]]
then
    echo $string is a float
elif [[ "$string" =~ ^-?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]*[eE]-?[0-9]+$ ]]
then
    echo $string is a scientific number
else
    echo $string is not a number
fi
```

Note: We could list the syntactical requirements for decimal and scientific notation, one being to allow comma as radix point, as well as ".". We would then assert that there must be only one such radix point. There can be two +/- signs in an [Ee] float. I have learned a few more rules from Aulu's work, and tested against bad strings such as '' '-' '-E-1' '0-0'. Here are my regex/substring/expr tools that seem to be holding up:

```
parse_num() {
 local r=`expr "$1" : '.*\([.,]\)' 2>/dev/null | tr -d '\n'` 
 nat='^[+-]?[0-9]+[.,]?$' \
 dot="${1%[.,]*}${r}${1##*[.,]}" \
 float='^[\+\-]?([.,0-9]+[Ee]?[-+]?|)[0-9]+$'
 [[ "$1" == $dot ]] && [[ "$1" =~ $float ]] || [[ "$1" =~ $nat ]]
} # usage: parse_num -123.456
```

Answer (score 7):

Can't comment yet so I'll add my own answer, which is an extension to glenn jackman's answer using bash pattern matching.

My original need was to identify numbers and distinguish integers and floats. The function definitions deducted to:

```
function isInteger() {
    [[ ${1} == ?(-)+([0-9]) ]]
}

function isFloat() {
    [[ ${1} == ?(-)@(+([0-9]).*([0-9])|*([0-9]).+([0-9]))?(E?(-|+)+([0-9])) ]]
}
```

I used unit testing (with shUnit2) to validate my patterns worked as intended:

```
oneTimeSetUp() {
    int_values="0 123 -0 -123"
    float_values="0.0 0. .0 -0.0 -0. -.0 \
        123.456 123. .456 -123.456 -123. -.456
        123.456E08 123.E08 .456E08 -123.456E08 -123.E08 -.456E08 \
        123.456E+08 123.E+08 .456E+08 -123.456E+08 -123.E+08 -.456E+08 \
        123.456E-08 123.E-08 .456E-08 -123.456E-08 -123.E-08 -.456E-08"
}

testIsIntegerIsFloat() {
    local value
    for value in ${int_values}
    do
        assertTrue "${value} should be tested as integer" "isInteger ${value}"
        assertFalse "${value} should not be tested as float" "isFloat ${value}"
    done

    for value in ${float_values}
    do
        assertTrue "${value} should be tested as float" "isFloat ${value}"
        assertFalse "${value} should not be tested as integer" "isInteger ${value}"
    done

}
```

Notes: The isFloat pattern can be modified to be more tolerant about decimal point (`@(.,)`) and the E symbol (`@(Ee)`). My unit tests test only values that are either integer or float, but not any invalid input.

Answer (score 6):

I use [expr](http://man.cx/expr). It returns a non-zero if you try to add a zero to a non-numeric value:

```bash
if expr -- "$number" + 0 > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "$number is a number"
else
    echo "$number isn't a number"
fi
```

It might be possible to use [bc](http://man.cx/bc) if you need non-integers, but I don't believe `bc` has quite the same behavior. Adding zero to a non-number gets you zero and it returns a value of zero too. Maybe you can combine `bc` and `expr`. Use `bc` to add zero to `$number`. If the answer is `0`, then try `expr` to verify that `$number` isn't zero.

Comment: This is rather bad. To make it slightly better you should use `expr -- "$number" + 0`; yet this will still pretend that `0 isn't a number`. From `man expr`: `Exit status is 0 if EXPRESSION is neither null nor 0, 1  if  EXPRESSION is  null  or  0,`

Comment: With Bash, you really should never need `expr`. If you are confined to a lesser Bourne shell like POSIX `sh`, then maybe.

Comment: POSIX sh is guaranteed to have `$(( ))`. You're talking 1970s Bourne to need `expr`.

Comment: @tripleee - May I ask why `expr` is not encouraged in Bash? I think this solution is POSIX compliant and **the most concise**. Yes it fails when `number=0`. It can be improved by `expr 1 + "$v" \* "$v"` which ensures the answer is not zero.

Comment: Because the external kitchen sink called `expr` made sense for th  original Bourne shell because it did not have equivalent or superior features built in; but that is no longer true for modern shells. Again, if you are shooting for POSIX compliance, there may be corner cases where there are no convenient equivalents to `expr`, but adding two integers is not one of them.

Answer (score 6):

One simple way is to check whether it contains non-digit characters. You replace all digit characters with nothing and check for length. If there's length it's not a number.

```
if [[ ! -n ${input//[0-9]/} ]]; then
    echo "Input Is A Number"
fi
```

Comment: To handle negative numbers would require a more complicated approach.

Comment: ... Or an optional positive sign.

Comment: @tripleee i'd like to see your approach if you know how to do it.

Comment: @andrew with this little change, your code work (using zsh) very fine! Even for negative or positive numbers: 
`[[ ! -n ${1//[+\-0-9]/} ]] && echo "is a number" || echo "is not a number";`. The problem now is that `+-123` will pass too.

Comment: Finally, I achieved expected result using some more changes beginning from your answer. Hope to help someone more.
https://gist.github.com/bernardolm/1c9e003a5f68e6e2534458fa758a096d

Comment: @BernardoLoureiro this catches one symbol sign at the beginning: `[ $var = ${var//[0-9]/}${var/[+\-]/} ]`

Answer (score 5):

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_03.html

You can also use bash's character classes.

```
if [[ $VAR = *[[:digit:]]* ]]; then
 echo "$VAR is numeric"
else
 echo "$VAR is not numeric"
fi
```

Numerics will include space, the decimal point, and "e" or "E" for floating point.

But, if you specify a C-style hex number, i.e. "0xffff" or "0XFFFF", [[:digit:]] returns true.  A bit of a trap here, bash allows you do to something like "0xAZ00" and still count it as a digit (isn't this from some weird quirk of GCC compilers that let you use 0x notation for bases other than 16???)

You might want to test for "0x" or "0X" before testing if it's a numeric if your input is completely untrusted, unless you want to accept hex numbers.  That would be accomplished by:

```
if [[ ${VARIABLE:1:2} = "0x" ]] || [[ ${VARIABLE:1:2} = "0X" ]]; then echo "$VAR is not numeric"; fi
```

Comment: `[[ $VAR = *[[:digit:]]* ]]` will return true if the variable **contains** a number, not if it **is** an integer.

Comment: `[[ "z3*&" = *[[:digit:]]* ]] && echo "numeric"` prints `numeric`. Tested in bash version `3.2.25(1)-release`.

Comment: @ultraswadable, your solution detects those strings containing, at least, one digit surrounded (or not) by any other characters. I downvoted.

Comment: The obviously correct approach is therefore to reverse this, and use `[[ -n $VAR && $VAR != *[^[:digit:]]* ]]`

Comment: @eschwartz , your solution doesn't work with negative numbers

Answer (score 5):

I use printf as other answers mentioned, if you supply the format string "%f" or "%i" printf will do the checking for you. Easier than reinventing the checks, the syntax is simple and short and printf is ubiquitous. So its a decent choice in my opinion - you can also use the following idea to check for a range of things, its not only useful for checking numbers.

```
declare  -r CHECK_FLOAT="%f"  
declare  -r CHECK_INTEGER="%i"  

 ## <arg 1> Number - Number to check  
 ## <arg 2> String - Number type to check  
 ## <arg 3> String - Error message  
function check_number() { 
  local NUMBER="${1}" 
  local NUMBER_TYPE="${2}" 
  local ERROR_MESG="${3}"
  local -i PASS=1 
  local -i FAIL=0   
  case "${NUMBER_TYPE}" in 
    "${CHECK_FLOAT}") 
        if ((! $(printf "${CHECK_FLOAT}" "${NUMBER}" &>/dev/random;echo $?))); then 
           echo "${PASS}"
        else 
           echo "${ERROR_MESG}" 1>&2
           echo "${FAIL}"
        fi 
        ;;                 
    "${CHECK_INTEGER}") 
        if ((! $(printf "${CHECK_INTEGER}" "${NUMBER}" &>/dev/random;echo $?))); then 
           echo "${PASS}"
        else 
           echo "${ERROR_MESG}" 1>&2
           echo "${FAIL}"
        fi 
        ;;                 
                     *) 
        echo "Invalid number type format: ${NUMBER_TYPE} to check_number()." 1>&2
        echo "${FAIL}"
        ;;                 
   esac
}
```

`>$ var=45`

`>$ (($(check_number $var "${CHECK_INTEGER}" "Error: Found $var - An integer is required."))) && { echo "$var+5" | bc; }`

Answer (score 5):

As i had to tamper with this lately and like *karttu's* appoach with the unit test the most. I revised the code and added some other solutions too, try it out yourself to see the results:

```
#!/bin/bash

    # N={0,1,2,3,...} by syntaxerror
function isNaturalNumber()
{
 [[ ${1} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
}
    # Z={...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...} by karttu
function isInteger() 
{
 [[ ${1} == ?(-)+([0-9]) ]]
}
    # Q={...,-½,-¼,0.0,¼,½,...} by karttu
function isFloat() 
{
 [[ ${1} == ?(-)@(+([0-9]).*([0-9])|*([0-9]).+([0-9]))?(E?(-|+)+([0-9])) ]]
}
    # R={...,-1,-½,-¼,0.E+n,¼,½,1,...}
function isNumber()
{
 isNaturalNumber $1 || isInteger $1 || isFloat $1
}

bools=("TRUE" "FALSE")
int_values="0 123 -0 -123"
float_values="0.0 0. .0 -0.0 -0. -.0 \
    123.456 123. .456 -123.456 -123. -.456 \
    123.456E08 123.E08 .456E08 -123.456E08 -123.E08 -.456E08 \
    123.456E+08 123.E+08 .456E+08 -123.456E+08 -123.E+08 -.456E+08 \
    123.456E-08 123.E-08 .456E-08 -123.456E-08 -123.E-08 -.456E-08"
false_values="blah meh mooh blah5 67mooh a123bc"

for value in ${int_values} ${float_values} ${false_values}
do
    printf "  %5s=%-30s" $(isNaturalNumber $value) ${bools[$?]} $(printf "isNaturalNumber(%s)" $value)
    printf "%5s=%-24s" $(isInteger $value) ${bools[$?]} $(printf "isInteger(%s)" $value)
    printf "%5s=%-24s" $(isFloat $value) ${bools[$?]} $(printf "isFloat(%s)" $value)
    printf "%5s=%-24s\n" $(isNumber $value) ${bools[$?]} $(printf "isNumber(%s)" $value)
done
```

So *isNumber()* includes dashes, commas and exponential notation and therefore returns TRUE on integers & floats where on the other hand *isFloat()* returns FALSE on integer values and *isInteger()* likewise returns FALSE on floats. For your convenience all as one liners:

```
isNaturalNumber() { [[ ${1} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; }
isInteger() { [[ ${1} == ?(-)+([0-9]) ]]; }
isFloat() { [[ ${1} == ?(-)@(+([0-9]).*([0-9])|*([0-9]).+([0-9]))?(E?(-|+)+([0-9])) ]]; }
isNumber() { isNaturalNumber $1 || isInteger $1 || isFloat $1; }
```

Comment: Personally I would remove the `function` keyword as it doesn't do anything useful. Also, I'm not sure about the usefulness of the return values. Unless otherwise specified, the functions will return the exit status of the last command, so you don't need to `return` anything yourself.

Comment: Nice, indeed the `return`s are confusing and make it less readable. Using `function` keywords or not is more a question of personal flavor at least i removed them from the one liners to save some space. thx.

Comment: Don't forget that semicolons are needed after the tests for the one-line versions.

Comment: isNumber will return 'true' on any string that has a number in it.

Comment: @DrStrangepork Indeed, my false_values array is missing that case. I will have look into it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Tried to create a combined regex expression for all three types. It's possible but this leads to a really complex regex gibberish. A mutex condition looks really simple and readable.

Answer (score 4):

I like Alberto Zaccagni's answer.

```
if [ "$var" -eq "$var" ] 2>/dev/null; then
```

Important prerequisites:
- no subshells spawned
- no RE parsers invoked
- most shell applications don't use real numbers

But if `$var` is complex (e.g. an associative array access), and if the number will be a non-negative integer (most use-cases), then this is perhaps more efficient?

```
if [ "$var" -ge 0 ] 2> /dev/null; then ..
```

Comment: This doesn't fail only for complex numbers (those with an imaginary component), but also for floating point numbers (those with a non-integer component).

Answer (score 2):

To catch negative numbers:

```
if [[ $1 == ?(-)+([0-9.]) ]]
    then
    echo number
else
    echo not a number
fi
```

Comment: Also, this requires extended globbing to be enabled first. This is a Bash-only feature which is disabled by default.

Comment: @tripleee extended globbing is activated automatically when using == or !=   `When the ‘==’ and ‘!=’ operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in Pattern Matching, as if the extglob shell option were enabled.`  https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b

Comment: @BadrElmers Thanks for the update. This seems to be a new behavior which is not true in my Bash 3.2.57 (MacOS Mojave). I see it works as you describe in 4.4.

Answer (score 2):

You could use "let" too like this :

```
[ ~]$ var=1
[ ~]$ let $var && echo "It's a number" || echo "It's not a number"
It\'s a number
[ ~]$ var=01
[ ~]$ let $var && echo "It's a number" || echo "It's not a number"
It\'s a number
[ ~]$ var=toto
[ ~]$ let $var && echo "It's a number" || echo "It's not a number"
It\'s not a number
[ ~]$
```

But I prefer use the "=~" Bash 3+ operator like some answers in this thread.

Comment: This is very dangerous. Don't evaluate unvalidated arithmetic in the shell. It must be validated some other way first.

Comment: @ormaaj why is it dangerous? As in malicious numbers, or overflows? Is it dangerous when the input is your own value?

Answer (score 2):

Almost as you want in syntax. Just need a function `isnumber`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

isnumber(){
  num=$1
  if [ -z "${num##*[!0-9]*}" ]; 
    then return 1
  else
    return 0
  fi
}

$(isnumber $1) && VAR=$1 || echo "need a number";
echo "VAR is $VAR"
```

test:

```
$ ./isnumtest 10
VAR is 10
$ ./isnumtest abc10
need a number
VAR is
```

**UPDATE 2024** (it still doesn't support floating point numbers)

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

isnumber(){
  if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo {empty string} isn\'t number
    return 1
  elif [ -z "${1##*[!0-9]*}" ]; then     
    echo $1 isn\'t number
    return 1
  else
    echo $1 is number 
    return 0
  fi
}

isnumber $1;
```

Comment: This incorrectly reports that an empy string is a number.

Comment: @tripleee how did you run the test? if I run `./isnumtest` or `./isnumtest ""` I get `need a number`

Comment: Sorry, I misread your logic. The calling code has multiple flaws, though; see [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable). The idiomatic formulation would be `isnumber "$1" && var=$1 || echo "Need a number: $1" >&2` (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Comment: In Bash, you would also declare `local num` to avoid clobbering any global variable with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf '%b' "-123\nABC" | tr '[:space:]' '_' | grep -q '^-\?[[:digit:]]\+$' && echo "Integer." || echo "NOT integer."
```

Remove the `-\?` in grep matching pattern if you don't accept negative integer.

Comment: Downvote for lack of explanation. How does this work? It looks complex and brittle, and it's not obvious what inputs exactly it will accept. (For example, is removing spaces crucially necessary? Why? It will say a number with embedded spaces is a valid number, which may not be desirable.)

Answer (score 1):

Did the same thing here with a regular expression that test the entire part and decimals part, separated with a dot.

```
re="^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$"

if [[ $1 =~ $re ]] 
then
   echo "is numeric"
else
  echo "Naahh, not numeric"
fi
```

Comment: Could you explain why your answer is fundamentally different from other old answers, e.g., Charles Duffy's answer? Well, your answer is actually broken since it validates a single period `.`

Comment: not sure to understand the single period here... it is one or zero period expected.... But right nothing fundamentally different, just found the regex easier to read.

Comment: also using * should match more real world cases

Comment: The thing is you're matching the empty string `a=''` and the string that contains a period only `a='.'` so your code is a bit broken...

Answer (score 1):

Easy-to-understand and compatible solution, with `test` command :

```
test $myVariable -eq 0 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -le 1 ]; then echo 'ok'; else echo 'KO'; fi
```

If myVariable = 0, the return code is 0
If myVariable > 0, the return code is 1
If myVariable is not an integer, the return code is 2

Answer (score 0):

I use the following (for integers):

```
## ##### constants
##
## __TRUE - true (0)
## __FALSE - false (1)
##
typeset -r __TRUE=0
typeset -r __FALSE=1

## --------------------------------------
## isNumber
## check if a value is an integer 
## usage: isNumber testValue 
## returns: ${__TRUE} - testValue is a number else not
##
function isNumber {
  typeset TESTVAR="$(echo "$1" | sed 's/[0-9]*//g' )"
  [ "${TESTVAR}"x = ""x ] && return ${__TRUE} || return ${__FALSE}
}

isNumber $1 
if [ $? -eq ${__TRUE} ] ; then
  print "is a number"
fi
```

Comment: Almost correct (you're accepting the empty string) but gratutiously complicated to the point of obfuscation.

Comment: Incorrect: you're accepting `-n`, etc. (because of `echo`), and you're accepting variables with trailing newlines (because of `$(...)`). And by the way, `print` is not a valid shell command.

Answer (score 0):

I tried ultrasawblade's recipe as it seemed the most practical to me, and couldn't make it work. In the end i devised another way though, based as others in parameter substitution, this time with regex replacement:

```
[[ "${var//*([[:digit:]])}" ]]; && echo "$var is not numeric" || echo "$var is numeric"
```

It removes every :digit: class character in $var and checks if we are left with an empty string, meaning that the original was only numbers.

What i like about this one is its small footprint and flexibility. In this form it only works for non-delimited, base 10 integers, though surely you can use pattern matching to suit it to other needs.

Comment: Reading mrucci's solution, it looks almost the same as mine, but using regular string replacement instead of "sed style". Both use the same rules for pattern matching and are, AFAIK, interchangeable solutions.

Comment: `sed` is POSIX, while your solution is `bash`. Both have their uses

Answer (score 0):

I found quite a short version:

```
function isnum()
{
    return `echo "$1" | awk -F"\n" '{print ($0 != $0+0)}'`
}
```

Comment: um.. doesn't this just return 0 if the string is not a number? Does that means it doesn't work if your string is `"0"`?

Answer (score 0):

- variable to check

  `number=12345` or `number=-23234` or `number=23.167` or `number=-345.234`
- check numeric or non-numeric

  `echo $number | grep -E '^-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$' > /dev/null`
- decide on further actions based on the exit status of the above

  `if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "Numeric"; else echo "Non-Numeric"; fi`

Answer (score 0):

Following up on [David W's answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/19614406) from Oct '13, if using `expr` this might be better

```
test_var=`expr $am_i_numeric \* 0` >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ "$test_var" = "" ]
then
    ......
```

If numeric, multiplied by 1 gives you the same value, (including negative numbers).  Otherwise you get `null` which you can test for

Comment: `expr` is a beast which is hard to tame. I have not tested this solution but I would avoid `expr` in favor of modern shell built-ins unless compatibility back to legacy shells from the early 1980s is an important requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant of implementation.

**if_math_expr.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Script both for execution and inclusion.
if [[ -n "$BASH" ]]; then

function if_math_expr()
{
  (( "$*" || ! "$*" )) 2> /dev/null && return 0
  return 1
}

if [[ -z "$BASH_LINENO" || BASH_LINENO[0] -eq 0 ]]; then
  # Script was not included, then execute it.
  if_math_expr "$@"
fi

fi
```

**if_int.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Script both for execution and inclusion.
if [[ -n "$BASH" ]]; then

function if_int()
{
  local __tmp=''
  if (( "$*" || ! "$*" )) 2> /dev/null; then
    (( __tmp = "$*" )) 2> /dev/null # assignment with evaluation and deduction
    [[ "$__tmp" == "$*" || "+$__tmp" == "$*" ]] && return 0 # test on not deduced expression
  fi
  return 1
}

if [[ -z "$BASH_LINENO" || BASH_LINENO[0] -eq 0 ]]; then
  # Script was not included, then execute it.
  if_int "$@"
fi

fi
```

**cast_to_int.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Script both for execution and inclusion.
if [[ -n "$BASH" ]]; then

# casts any not integer and not deduced value to 0, otherwise leave as is
function cast_to_int()
{
  local __tmp
  local __var
  local __value
  for __var in "$@"; do
    if (( "$__var" || ! "$__var" )) 2> /dev/null; then
      if [[ -n "$__var" ]]; then
        eval "__value=\"\$$__var\""
      else
        __value=''
      fi
      echo "__value=$__value"
      if [[ -n "$__value" && "$__value" != "__value" ]]; then # bash issue workaround for variable '_'
        __tmp=''
        (( __tmp = "$__var" )) 2> /dev/null # assignment with evaluation and deduction
        echo "__tmp=$__tmp"
        if [[ "$__tmp" != "$__value" && "+$__tmp" != "$__value" ]]; then # test on not deduced expression
          (( "$__var" = 0 )) # reset to 0 because deduced expression still is not an integer
        fi
      else
        (( "$__var" = 0 )) # reset to 0 if empty
      fi
    else
      (( "$__var" = 0 )) # reset to 0 because is not a math expression
    fi
  done
}

if [[ -z "$BASH_LINENO" || BASH_LINENO[0] -eq 0 ]]; then
  # Script was not included, then execute it.
  cast_to_int "$@"
fi

fi
```

**Tests:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

. ./if_math_expr.sh

function call()
{
  echo "> $*"
  eval "$*"
}

# caution: `_` variable name is reserved

call "_=''"
call "__=''"
call 'a=+0'
call 'b=-1'
call 'c=-0+0'
call 'd=1/1'
call 'e=1/0'
call 'f=1a'

echo ''

call './if_math_expr.sh && echo true'
call './if_math_expr.sh +0 && echo true'
call './if_math_expr.sh -1 && echo true'
call './if_math_expr.sh -0+0 && echo true'
call './if_math_expr.sh 1/1 && echo true'
call './if_math_expr.sh 1/0 && echo true'
call './if_math_expr.sh 1a && echo true'

echo ''

call './if_math_expr.sh _ && echo true'
call './if_math_expr.sh __ && echo true'
call './if_math_expr.sh a && echo true'
call './if_math_expr.sh b && echo true'
call './if_math_expr.sh c && echo true'
call './if_math_expr.sh d && echo true'
call './if_math_expr.sh e && echo true'
call './if_math_expr.sh f && echo true'

echo ''

call './if_int.sh && echo true'
call './if_int.sh +0 && echo true'
call './if_int.sh -1 && echo true'
call './if_int.sh -0+0 && echo true'
call './if_int.sh 1/1 && echo true'
call './if_int.sh 1/0 && echo true'
call './if_int.sh 1a && echo true'

echo ''

call './if_int.sh _ && echo true'
call './if_int.sh __ && echo true'
call './if_int.sh a && echo true'
call './if_int.sh b && echo true'
call './if_int.sh c && echo true'
call './if_int.sh d && echo true'
call './if_int.sh e && echo true'
call './if_int.sh f && echo true'

echo ''

call '. ./cast_to_int.sh && cast_to_int _ __ a b c d e f'

echo ''

echo "_=$_"
echo "__=$__"
echo "a=$a"
echo "b=$b"
echo "c=$c"
echo "d=$d"
echo "e=$e"
echo "f=$f"
```

**Result:**

```bash
$ ./test.sh
> _=''
> __=''
> a=+0
> b=-1
> c=-0+0
> d=1/1
> e=1/0
> f=1a

> ./if_math_expr.sh && echo true
> ./if_math_expr.sh +0 && echo true
true
> ./if_math_expr.sh -1 && echo true
true
> ./if_math_expr.sh -0+0 && echo true
true
> ./if_math_expr.sh 1/1 && echo true
true
> ./if_math_expr.sh 1/0 && echo true
> ./if_math_expr.sh 1a && echo true

> ./if_math_expr.sh _ && echo true
true
> ./if_math_expr.sh __ && echo true
true
> ./if_math_expr.sh a && echo true
true
> ./if_math_expr.sh b && echo true
true
> ./if_math_expr.sh c && echo true
true
> ./if_math_expr.sh d && echo true
true
> ./if_math_expr.sh e && echo true
true
> ./if_math_expr.sh f && echo true
true

> ./if_int.sh && echo true
> ./if_int.sh +0 && echo true
true
> ./if_int.sh -1 && echo true
true
> ./if_int.sh -0+0 && echo true
> ./if_int.sh 1/1 && echo true
> ./if_int.sh 1/0 && echo true
> ./if_int.sh 1a && echo true

> ./if_int.sh _ && echo true
> ./if_int.sh __ && echo true
> ./if_int.sh a && echo true
> ./if_int.sh b && echo true
> ./if_int.sh c && echo true
> ./if_int.sh d && echo true
> ./if_int.sh e && echo true
> ./if_int.sh f && echo true

> . ./cast_to_int.sh && cast_to_int _ __ a b c d e f
__value=__value
__value=
__value=+0
__tmp=0
__value=-1
__tmp=-1
__value=-0+0
__tmp=0
__value=1/1
__tmp=1

_=
__=0
a=+0
b=-1
c=0
d=0
e=0
f=0
```

```bash
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
```

Answer (score -1):

Quick & Dirty: I know it's not the most elegant way, but I usually just added a zero to it and test the result. like so:

```
function isInteger {
  [ $(($1+0)) != 0 ] && echo "$1 is a number" || echo "$1 is not a number"
 }

x=1;      isInteger $x
x="1";    isInteger $x
x="joe";  isInteger $x
x=0x16 ;  isInteger $x
x=-32674; isInteger $x
```

$(($1+0)) will return 0 or bomb if $1 is NOT an integer. for Example:

```
function zipIt  { # quick zip - unless the 1st parameter is a number
  ERROR="not a valid number. " 
  if [ $(($1+0)) != 0 ] ; then  # isInteger($1) 
      echo " backing up files changed in the last $1 days."
      OUT="zipIt-$1-day.tgz" 
      find . -mtime -$1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 tar cvzf $OUT 
      return 1
  fi
    showError $ERROR
}
```

NOTE: I guess I never thought to check for floats or mixed types that will make the entire script bomb... in my case, I didn't want it go any further. I'm gonna play around with mrucci's solution and Duffy's regex - they seem the most robust within the bash framework...

Comment: This accepts arithmetic expressions like `1+1`, but rejects some positive integers with leading `0`s (because `08` is an invalid octal constant).

Comment: This has other issues too: `0` is not a number, and it is subject to arbitrary code injection, try it: `isInteger 'a[$(ls)]'`. Ooops.

Comment: And the expansion of `$((...))` is unquoted, a numeric `IFS=123` will change it.

Comment: Test: `a=5; set -- a ; echo $(($1+0))`  . Where `$1` contain `a`  which is not a number, but answer is `5`!

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me in all cases BASH 4+ so :

```
# -- is var an integer? --
# trim leading/trailing whitespace, then check for digits return 0 or 1
# Globals: None
# Arguments: string
# Returns: boolean
# --
is_int() {
    str="$(echo -e "${1}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
    case ${str} in ''|*[!0-9]*) return 1 ;; esac
    return 0
}
```

How to use it ?

Valid (will return 0 = true):

```
is_int "100" && echo "return 0" || echo "return 1"
```

Invalid (will return 1 = false) :

```
is_int "100abc" && echo "returned 0" || echo "returned 1"
is_int ""  && echo "returned 0" || echo "returned 1"
is_int "100 100"  && echo "returned 0" || echo "returned 1"
is_int "      "  && echo "returned 0" || echo "returned 1"
is_int $NOT_SET_VAR  && echo "returned 0" || echo "returned 1"
is_int "3.14"   && echo "returned 0" || echo "returned 1"
```

Output:

```
returned 0
returned 1
returned 1
returned 1
returned 1
returned 1
returned 1
```

note, in Bash, 1 = false, 0 = true. I am simply printing it out where instead something like this would be more likely  :

```
if is_int ${total} ; then
    # perform some action 
fi
```

Comment: Could I ask you to show a specific case the accepted answer doesn't work for?

Comment: ...btw, `echo -e` is going to introduce portability bugs -- on some shells it prints `-e` on output (and those shells where it *doesn't* do so are violating the letter of the [POSIX specification for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html); with the right set of runtime flags set to make it more strictly compliant than usual, this means bash too can print `-e` on output when you run `echo -e`).

Answer (score -1):

### Shortest

```bash
[ -z "${n//[0-9]}" ] && echo IS_NUMBER
```

or

```bash
test -z "${n//[0-9]}" && echo IS_NUMBER
```

or

```bash
[[ "$n" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && echo IS_NUMBER
```

Comment: This seems to merely repeat solutions from previous answers.

Answer (score -3):

The accepted answer does not work here, I am on MacOS. The following code works:

```
if [ $(echo "$number" | grep -c '^[0-9]\+$') = 0 ]; then 
    echo "it is a number"
else
    echo "not a number"
fi
```

Comment: This has many problems: the most obvious one is that you should compare with `1` and not `0` in the test statement. The other problem is if variable `number` contains newlines: `number=$'42\nthis is not a number, right?'` will be validated.

Comment: Eh? The accepted answer does indeed work on MacOS. Please comment on it with details of the issue seen, and (ideally) a reproducer. (I suspect that perhaps it was being run under `/bin/sh` -- either via a `#!/bin/sh` shebang or with a script started with `sh scriptname` -- rather than bash).

Comment: Using `grep -c` in a command substitution and comparing the result to 0 is a common and extremely convoluted antipattern. See [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) and the "pretzel logic" subpage.

Answer (score -4):

Stack popped a message asked me if I really want to answer after 30+ answers? But of course!!!
Use bash new features and here it is: (after the comment I made a change)

> <del>function isInt() {    ([[ $1 -eq $(( $1 + 0 )) ]] 2>/dev/null &&
>   [[ $1 != '' ]] && echo 1) || echo '' }</del>

```
function isInt() {
   ([[ $1 =~ ^[-+0-9]+$  ]] && [[ $1 -eq $(( $1 + 0 )) ]] 2>/dev/null && [[ $1 != '' ]] && echo 1) || echo ''
}
```

Supports:

```
===============out-of-the-box==================
 1. negative integers (true & arithmetic),
 2. positive integers (true & arithmetic),
 3. with quotation (true & arithmetic),
 4. without quotation (true & arithmetic),
 5. all of the above with mixed signs(!!!) (true & arithmetic),
 6. empty string (false & arithmetic),
 7. no value (false & arithmetic),
 8. alphanumeric (false & no arithmetic),
 9. mixed only signs (false & no arithmetic),
================problematic====================
 10. positive/negative floats with 1 decimal (true & NO arithmetic),
 11. positive/negative floats with 2 or more decimals (FALSE & NO arithmetic).
```

True/false is what you get from the function **only when used** combined with process substitution like in `[[ $( isInt <arg> ) ]]` as there is no *logical* type in bash neither *return* value of function.

I use capital when the result of the test expression is WRONG whereas, it should be the reverse!

By 'arithmetic' I mean bash **can do** math like in this expression: `$x=$(( $y + 34))`.

I use 'arithmetic/no arithmetic' when in mathematical expressions the argument acts as it is expected and 'NO arithmetic' when it misbehaves compared with what it is expected.

As you see, only no 10 and 11 are the problematic ones!

Perfect!

PS: Note that the **MOST** popular answer **fails** in case 9!

Comment: No, please no!!! this is completely broken! and it is subject to arbitrary code execution. Try it yourself: `isInt 'a[$(ls>&3)]' 3>&1`. You're glad I only used `ls` as a command (which is executed twice). And your code also claims that `a[$(ls>&3)]` is a number.

Comment: Not to mention that it will claim that any valid variable name (which is unset or expands to a number or empty, or recursively expands to a number or empty) is a number. E.g., `unset a; isInt a`.

Comment: arbitrary code execution by whom? you take the responsibility to type sudo su but not to execute this or any script?

Comment: if [[ isInt 'a[$(ls>&3)]' ]]; then ... is safe as it gives ... errors! You mean direct execution  isInt 'a[$(ls>&3)]' .... then don't call it direct!! You imply what if an rm was inside ... I would reply 'don't you know what rm does?' I agree, just test it and its OK under conditions! Just like life is!

Answer (score -5):

This is a little rough around the edges but a little more novice friendly.

```
if [ $number -ge 0 ]
then
echo "Continue with code block"
else
echo "We matched 0 or $number is not a number"
fi
```

This will cause an error and print "Illegal number:" if $number is not a number but it will not break out of the script. Oddly there is not a test option I could find to just test for an integer.
The logic here will match any number that is greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: Your test misses 0, not to mention negative numbers.

Comment: also, this requires `[[ ]]`, instead of `[ ]`, otherwise it fails on non-integer strings.

Comment: [ "$number" -ge 0 2>/dev/null ] && echo isNumber || echo noNumber

Comment: `-ge` is greater than or equal, so it shouldn't miss 0, but it would miss negative numbers.  The above solution also works better, since `[[ ]]` would always result in a number for @defim's answer, but works nicely for `[ ]` since it would generate an error and evaluate to false.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the negative above. For all use: ```[ "$number" -eq "$number" 2>/dev/null ] && echo isNumber || echo noNumber```

Answer (score -5):

Below is a Script written by me and used for a script integration with Nagios and it is working properly till now

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to test variable is numeric or not
# Shirish Shukla
# Pass arg1 as number
a1=$1
a=$(echo $a1|awk '{if($1 > 0) print $1; else print $1"*-1"}')
b=$(echo "scale=2;$a/$a + 1" | bc -l 2>/dev/null)
if [[ $b > 1 ]]
then
    echo "$1 is Numeric"
else
    echo "$1 is Non Numeric"
fi
```

EG:

```
# sh isnumsks.sh   "-22.22"
-22.22 is Numeric

# sh isnumsks.sh   "22.22"
22.22 is Numeric

# sh isnumsks.sh   "shirish22.22"
shirish22.22 is Non  Numeric
```

Comment: This is complex and broken. You need double quotes in `echo "$a1"`, otherwise wildcards in the string are expanded and the outcome depends on what files are in the current directory (try `isnumsks.sh "*"`, then try again after creating a file called `42`). You're only looking at the first whitespace-delimited word, so `42 psych` is misclassified as numeric. All kinds of input that are not numeric but valid `bc` syntax will screw this up, e.g. `2012-01-03`.