# Linux bash scripts

Tags: bash, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I test if a variable is a number in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash)

I am new to bash scripts. Needed a code to check whether a variable is a number, if YES i have to keep it as it, if NO i ll have to reassign it to some other value. How do I get this done?

Comment: Some particular number or that it's not a non-number? Integer or float? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Your basic `if () then ... fi`. Here's the format:

```
#!/bin/bash

var=2

if [[ $var != 1 ]]
then
    var=5;
fi

echo $var
```

Note that the `[[...]]` format can actually be one of many things.

As with everything, if you want to get good at it, you'll have to **work for it**. 
Type

- `man bash`
- `man test`

to get the manuals on the tools you're using. Read them top to bottom, again, again, and once more. And then tomorrow the same thing.