# check if the argument is a number inside the shell script

Tags: shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I test if a variable is a number in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash)

I try writing the fibonacci sequence by shell scripting for example if user entered `5` after the script name in the command line the script needs to print out the 5 fibonacci numbers from the beginning which are:

```
0 1 1 2 3
```

I have completed the script but I need to check the user input if it is positive number that I have a problem in this part.
in the command line the user should call the script and then enter a positive number

```
./script number
```

and this is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ $# -ne 1 ] && { echo "enter a number please" ; exit 1 ; } 
[ ! echo $1 | egrep -q '^[0-9]+$' &&  $1 -lt 0  ] && { echo "negative" ; exit 1 ; }

f0=0
f1=1
counter=2
if [ $1 -eq 0 ] ; then
echo -n "0"
elif [ $1 -ge 1 ] ; then
    echo -n "0 1" 
fi
    while [ $counter -le $1 ] && [ $1 -gt 1 ] ; do
        echo -n "$fn "      
        fn=`expr $f0 + $f1`
        f0=$f1
        f1=$fn
        counter=`expr $counter + 1`
    done 
echo ""
```

Comment: @sampson-chen didnt work. I checked it before asking the question. It didnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if [ $1 -ge 0 2>/dev/null ] ; then
```

it works for positive numbers equal or greater than 0

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at this:

http://www.bashguru.com/2010/12/how-to-validate-integer-input-using.html

Apparently someone wrote multiple shell scripts to do exactly that.

Comment: it works but if you enter a letter in the input it gives you an error about comparing a letter by 0

Comment: The linked page is infested with auto-forwarding ads. Don't visit unless you're feeling unstoppable.