# Linux Shell if-statements

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a script to add integers together. My first script works to add numbers

```
for number in $@; do
sum=$(($sum + $number))
done

echo $sum
```

Now I am trying to write an if statement that checks if $number is an valid integer and if not display an error message and kill the script.

```
if [ -z $number]; then
sum=$(($sum + $number))
else
echo $number
echo "Sorry, $number is not a number"
exit
fi
```

I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours and keep getting stuck and help would be nice

Comment: Did you mean to tag this with "bash" instead of "base"?

Comment: Unless you have some compelling reason, I suggest you not try to program in bash. bash/sh have grown well beyond their original capabilities and you pay for it in very arcane syntax. People more often script Python now where they would have used sh/bash or Perl in the past. For some tasks the shell is fine; it is hard to do `ls -lt | head -10 | awk '{print $2}'` more concisely. For things like addition, it's a bit irksome.

Answer (score 2):

The `-z` operator doesn't check if the string is a number, it checks if the length of the string is zero.

There isn't an operator to check if a string is an integer, however there are several ways to do this in bash.  [The answers on this previous discussion should be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash).

Answer (score 2):

the `-z` test will just test of the variable is empty (zero length) or not.  If you want to know that is has an integer you could use a regex match like

```
if [[ $number =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    sum=$((sum + number))
else
    echo "Sorry, $number is not a number"
    exit
 fi
```

Comment: Stick a `-?` after the `^` to accommodate negative integers as well.