# Bash - return a boolean check

Tags: bash

I created a simple function which does a regex check:

```
function is_number()
{
    return [[ "$1" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]
}
```

What I get is

```
return: [[: numeric argument required
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aside: The `function` keyword is a bashism that adds no significant value over the POSIX-defined function definition syntax; consider just using `is_number() {`, which will work with all POSIX-compliant shells.

Comment: ...btw, sorta-related (to the code shown as an example of contents, and including some POSIX-compliant answers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the `return` statement. The return value of the function is the exit code of the last statement. So this is enough:

```
function is_number()
{
    [[ "$1" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]
}
```

The equivalent of this using an explicit `return` statement would be:

```
function is_number()
{
    [[ "$1" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]
    return $?
}
```

But don't do this, it's pointless.