# How do i print square root of user input in bash?

Tags: bash

I have recently discovered 'bc' in bash, and i have been trying to use it to print out the square root of a user input. The program i wrote below runs successfully, but it only prints out '0' and not the square root of the user input.

Here is the code i wrote:

```
 #!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash

 echo "input value below"
 read VAR
 echo "square root of $VAR is..."

 echo $((a))                                  
 a=$(bc <<< "scale=0; sqrt(($VAR))")
```

What is the problem with my code? What am i missing?

Comment: Use [\[ shellcheck \]](https://shellcheck.net) to spot out script issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `bc` command and the use of command substitution is correct, the problem is you have provided the `echo $a` earlier, when it was unset. Do:

```
a=$(bc <<< "scale=0; sqrt($VAR)")
echo "$a"
```

Also while expanding variables, you should use the usual notation for variable expansion which is `$var` or `${var}`. I have also removed a pair of redundant `()` from `sqrt()`.

Comment: Also, `read -p "input value below" var` ie `VAR->var`. Use of full uppercase variables in shell-script is discouraged.

Comment: As the user input should not be trusted. You need to check if it is a number before passing it to `bc`. You may use `if [ "$var" -eq "$var" ] 2>/dev/null;then a=$(bc <<< "scale=0; sqrt($var)") else echo "$var not number"; fi`, a concept I've borrowed from [\[ here \]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/808740/1620779).

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have a number in variable `var` and you want square root of that variable. You can also use awk:

```
a=$(awk -v x=$var 'BEGIN{print sqrt(x)}')
```

or

```
a=$(echo "$var" | awk '{print sqrt($1)}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` is also possible. For instance, the following example shows 30 decimals of the square root of 98:

```
awk "BEGIN {printf \"%.30f\n\", sqrt(98)}"
```

The command above will output `9.899494936611665352188538236078`, which you can then store into the `a` variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `qalc` program installed (`apt-get install qalc`) then you can do squareroot and other calculations more easily (in my opinion) than by using `bc`.

Square root can be done like this:

`qalc "sqrt(36)"`

The man page isn't very helpful (for my installed version at least) but you can get more info here:

- https://github.com/Qalculate/libqalculate
- https://qalculate.github.io/manual/qalc.html
- https://qalculate.github.io/reference/index.html