# How to test if variable is a number with certain max digits in linux non-bash shell script

Tags: regex, linux, shell, numbers, ash

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash#3951175) I found nice solution to test if variable is a number:

```
case $string in
   ''|*[!0-9]*) echo bad ;;
   *) echo good ;;
esac
```

I'm trying to modify it to test if variable is a 1,2,3 or 4-digit natural number (within a range 0-9999), so I added `|*[0-9]{5,}*` to exclude numbers with more than 5 digits, but the code below prints `good` for numbers greater then 9999 e.g. 1234567.

```
case $string in
   ''|*[!0-9]*|*[0-9]{5,}*) echo bad ;;
   *) echo good ;;
esac
```

I'm using ash from busybox.

Comment: I mixed up **regular expressions** with **shell patterns**. According to ash man documentation: 
_A pattern consists of normal characters, which match themselves, and
     meta-characters.  The meta-characters are “!”, “*”, “?”, and “[”.  These
     characters lose their special meanings if they are quoted._

So `{5,}*` is not recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you need this in a case statement, since I would just do:

```
if { test "$string" -ge 0 && test "$string" -lt 10000; } 2> /dev/null; then
  echo good
else 
  echo bad
fi
```

If you want to use a case statement in a strictly portable shell, you're probably stuck with:

```
case $string in 
    [0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]) echo good;;
     *) echo bad;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numeric testing:

```
$ s=123
$ (( s>=0 && s<=9999 )) && echo "true" || echo "false"
true
$ s=123456
$ (( s>=0 && s<=9999 )) && echo "true" || echo "false"
false
$ s=-1
$ (( s>=0 && s<=9999 )) && echo "true" || echo "false"
false
```

You just need to make sure that the string is all digits with optional `±` at the start. A non numeric string used in numeric context will evaluate to `0` so you need to test for that.

Which you can use your case statement for:

```
case $s in 
  ''|*[!0-9]*) echo bad ;;
  *) (( s>=0 && s<=9999 )) && echo "true" || echo "false" ;;
esac
```

Or:

```
$ [ "$s" -eq "$s" ] 2>/dev/null && (( s>=0 && s<=9999 )) && echo "true" || echo "false"
```

Works too.

These *should* work under any POSIX shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
case  $([[ $num =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && echo 0) in
 0) echo good ;;
*) echo bad ;;
esac
```