# Compare Numbers not working properly (Bash Script in Hacker Rank)

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sh

According to the problem stated in the below link:

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/bash-and-linux-shell-practice/challenges/bash-tutorials---comparing-numbers/problem

My code is working fine in Mac OSX terminal, but while submitting the same code in Hackerrank one of the test case is failing. I am not sure why this is happening. Would really appreciate any answers.

```
 read X
 read Y

 if [[ $X > $Y ]]
 then 
   echo "X is greater than Y"
 elif [[ $X < $Y ]]
 then
   echo "X is less than Y"
 else
   echo "X is equal to Y"
 fi

 HackerRank Custom Test Case:

 Compilation Successful
 Input (stdin)
 -100
 100
 Your Output
 X is greater than Y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting that result; I get "X is less than Y" in actual bash. However, your script is actually wrong in a different way: in `[[ ]]`, `<` and `>` do alphabetic comparison rather than numeric comparison. To understand the difference, consider that `[[ 5 < 1000 ]]` will come out as false, because "5" comes after "1" in character sorting order. To do numeric comparison, use `-lt` and `-gt` instead.

Comment: Before, after, bigger, smaller -- I still count on my fingers! ;-)

Comment: I am also getting the correct answer in the Mac Terminal, as stated in the problem statement. But while submitting the solution on Hackerrank it is showing the above error.
Though I am very pleased, as the comment is very informative.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Bash [double-parenthesis](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html) context `((...))` vs test context `[[ ... ]]` to get more typical arithmetic comparisons:

```
x=-5
y=5

if ((x>y)); then 
    echo "X is greater than Y"
elif ((x<y)); then
    echo "X is less than Y"
else
    echo "X is equal to Y"
fi
```

Or use an [integer comparison](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) inside `[[ ... ]]` test:

```
if [[ "$x" -gt "$y" ]]; then
    echo "X is greater than Y"
elif [[ "$x" -lt "$y" ]]; then
    echo "X is less than Y"
else
    echo "X is equal to Y"
fi
```

Inside `[[ ... ]]` the `<`,`>` or `==` tests string comparisons.

Both of these methods only work with integers; to use floats, you need to use `awk`, `bc` or other float interpreter. Be sure to use double quotes `"$x"` in the `[[ test ]]` and the quotes and sigil are not required for `(( ))`

With user input, be sure to test that `$x` and `$y` are actual
numbers. Good tests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash)...

Comment: Your solution does work in Mac terminal as well as on HackerRank. I see what I did wrong,   but the question now is why my solution working in Mac Terminal and not in HackerRank.

Comment: The issue with HackerRank is how you read the values for x and y. Both solutions I have there work if you put `read x` and `read y` at the top of the code submission.