# How to use a function with parameters in an if statement in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
#!/bin/bash

check_for_int()
{
    if [ "$1" -eq "$1" ] 2>/dev/null
    then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

if [[check_for_int($1) == 1]]
    echo "FATAL: argument must be an integer!"
    exit 1
fi

# do stuff
```

However, no matter how I put it, `shellcheck` is complaining:

```
if [[ check_for_int($1) == 1 ]]; then
^-- SC1009: The mentioned parser error was in this if expression.
   ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this test expression.
               ^-- SC1036: '(' is invalid here. Did you forget to escape it?
               ^-- SC1072: Expected "]". Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

I have no idea why this isn't working...

Comment: Closely related: [How do I test if a variable is a number in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you pass argument to `check_for_int` is not valid in bash. Modify it to:

```
if ! check_for_int "$1"; then
    echo "FATAL: argument must be an integer!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: `check_for_int "$1"`, rather. Otherwise you'd get a result that `"1 abc"` is an integer, because only the `1` would end up in `$1`, and the `abc` would be in `$2`.

Answer (score 0):

**Like asked from title this is a working solution (Updated with better method used from @usr of pass arguments to a function in the if statement)**

```
#!/bin/bash

check_for_int () {
    if [[ $1 =~ ^\+?[0-9]+$ ]] || [[ $1 =~ ^\-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

if ! check_for_int "$1"; then
    echo "FATAL: argument must be an integer!"
    exit 1
else
    echo "${0}: ${1} is a integer!"
    exit 0
fi
```

**NOTE:**

**This include positive and negative sign**

**"$var" -eq "$var" have some negative side: [How do I test if a variable is a number in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash/808740#808740)**

**OUTPUT**

```
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ bash ex -+33
FATAL: argument must be an integer!
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ bash ex +33
ex: +33 is a integer!
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ bash ex -33
ex: -33 is a integer!
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ bash ex 3e33
FATAL: argument must be an integer!
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ bash ex '333 8'
FATAL: argument must be an integer!
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$
```

Comment: You'd get identical behavior from `check_for_int() { (( $1 == $1 )) 2>/dev/null; }` -- there's no point to the `if` and the explicit `return`s.

Comment: Also, you're comparing the _output_ of the function to `1`, but you don't actually print anything.

Comment: (and using the `function` keyword breaks POSIX compatibility for no good reason -- sure, `(( ))` does too, but that at least adds value in terms of enabling more idiomatic code).

Comment: Moreover, `(( $1 == $1 ))` isn't a safe way to check for integer-ness -- note that `abc` will evaluate to `0` if evaluated in an arithmetic context, unless there's a variable by that name defined with a different value. Thus, `set -- abc; unset abc; (( $1 == $1 ))` returns true with no error.

Comment: @Charles Duffy This solution is what the question ask us. POSIX regex is the better way to do it.

Comment: @Darby_Crash, if how to detect whether a value is a number is *truly* what the OP asked (rather than how to use a function with parameters in an if statement), then we should close the question as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash. That said, yes, (as you'll note from my answer on that question), I *do* agree that an ERE is an appropriate tool for the job.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, I like your comments, you have always a right point of view. ;)