# What is the proper way of filtering type errors in Bash scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Some years ago, while we were learning Bash script, our teacher taught us that the first thing we should do was filtering the "type" of the arguments given and throw an error in case they were different from expected.

(e. g., if our script takes 2 arguments to sum them, we should first check if they were indeed numbers)

The method he told us to use was `sed` command.

In the example above, we would take all the characters from the arguments that are different from numbers, and if there's any, we would consider it as a non numerical value, throwing an error.

Since this method looks pretty rudimentary to me, I would like to ask:

Is there any elegant way of achieving this?

Is this process actually done when building scripts?

Comment: There's no overly great way of doing so. See rather https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash

Comment: I think if you care about enforcing strong type safety, shell is not the right language for you.

Comment: Regex matching is probably how you would go about it. But in bash its pretty slow all things considered. You if writing a script comparing numbers, you could do something like `for i in $@, do echo $i | grep -q "[a-zA-Z]"; [[ $? == 0 ]] && echo "all good" || echo "try again"; exit 1; done` My personal preference is counting arguments, and spitting out the help menu if it's wrong. Gives the user a chance to read what your script was designed to do.

Comment: @itChi Your quoting is wrong and explicitly comparing `$?` is an antipattern. You mean `for i in "$@"; do if echo "$i" | grep -q '[a-zA-Z]'; then echo "all good"; else echo "try again"; exit 1; fi; done`

Comment: @tripleee Always learn something from you. I didn't test `grep '[a-zA-Z]'` assumed it would take my regex literally?

Comment: If you mean "why did I change from double to single quotes" it's just a dearly earned habit when dealing with regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` is tedious overkill when the shell has this functionality built in.

```
case $1 in *[!0-9]*) echo "$0: not a number: $1" >&2; exit 127;; esac
```

(If you want to allow for negative numbers or non-integers, obviously adapt the glob pattern.)

The shell itself doesn't have any types at all -- everything is a string.