# Bash: Check a String is a Number (whatever the format)

Tags: bash, awk, scientific-notation

I would like to share a way to check a string is a number in bash. This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash), but the answer fits only for either integers or floats in classical format, when a number can be in scientific format, and it uses complex regex. Second, I don't have enough reputation to answer the existing question (totally fresh account here...).

So the question is:

**How to (Easily) Check a String is a Number in bash?**

with the string being like:

```
"1234"
"-1.234"
"1.23e4"
"+1.23E04"
etc.
```

Answer in the... answer below.

Comment: Please check if the question already exists before opening a new one. See [How do I test if a variable is a number in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash#3951175)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22106305/1745001.

Comment: Zrin, I explain why I opened a new one in the text of the question (not enough reputation to answer existing thread).

Comment: Ed Morton, yes, I saw this one afterwards and indeed it's the same logic. Too bad it's lost in the flow of answers. The accepted one is not the best. Then, I think "returning" (printing) "true" or "false" is better than 1 or 0, because its a boolean. With the present solution, this works: if IsNumber $var; then (...) fi.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to use awk like this:

```
function IsNumber {

    echo "$1" | awk '{if ($1+0 == $1) print "true"; else print "false"}'

}
```

Examples:

```
$ IsNumber 1234
true
$ IsNumber 1.234
true
$ IsNumber 1.23E04
true
$ IsNumber abc
false
```

Comment: The idiomatic way to tell awk to treat a strnum (e.g. $1) as a number is to add zero and so the idiomatic awk code to test for $1 being a number is `$1+0 == $1` rather than `$1*1 == $1`.

Comment: Hi Ed Morton. Is this a question of style or is there an advantage to take +0 instead of *1? (eg. is it quicker?)

Comment: idk, I've been using it for 30+ years and haven't thought about it... I suppose MAYBE addition is faster than multiplication or maybe `+0` has less floating point rounding error possibility than `*1`? The main argument for using it AFAIK is that everyone knows exactly what it is when they see it since it's what's been used for years in scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the info Ed Morton.