# Is there a command to check the datatype of the input?

Tags: bash

Is there any command in Bash Scripting to check for the datatype of the input.

for example in python:

```py
type("this is a string") # would give a string
type(456) # would give a int
```

Comment: And this might be what you need to do instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash

Comment: yeah it does @StephenC Thanks alot!