# Conditional negation w/ bash

Tags: bash

I'm doing a basic script that asks the user some details about him/her. The fact is that I want to put the condition if the user doesn't put an age (number) the script warns with a message. I know there was somehow putting something like :

if [ $age != [0-9] ]

But it's not working whatsoever.

Any suggestion?

Ty.

Comment: ...I'm sure I've answered this question before, but the duplicates are mighty hard to search.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I test if a variable is a number in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash)

Comment: @kevin : The _test_  command only tests for string equality/inequality. See `man test`. For wildcard pattern matching, you need the bash construct `[[ ... ]]`.

Answer (score 7):

Pick your favourite: all of these **require** the use of the [double-bracket conditional construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b)

```sh
# is not all digits, regular expression
if [[ ! $age =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; ...

# contains a non-digit, regular expression
if [[ $age =~ [^0-9] ]]; ...

# contains a non-digit, glob pattern
if [[ $age == *[^0-9]* ]]; ...

# is not all digits, extended glob pattern
if [[ $age != +([0-9]) ]]; ...
```

In all of those methods, `0-9` can be replaced with the POSIX character class `[:digit:]`

```sh
if [[ $age == *[^[:digit:]]* ]]; ...
```

Documents:

- [bash pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)
- bash uses [extended regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/posix_002dextended-regular-expression-syntax.html#posix_002dextended-regular-expression-syntax)

Answer (score 5):

Glenn has covered the bash-only answers. The POSIX way that'll work even with `/bin/sh` is to use `case` instead of `if`:

```
case $age in
  *[!0-9]*) echo "Age must not contain non-numeric digits";;
esac
```