# Running multiple commands if an || condition is false

Tags: bash

So I'm having a bit of a problem when running this command in bash;

```
echo "$usr_age" | grep "^[0-9]*$" > $null || echo "Please only use numbers in the Age field." || exit 1
```

When running it, if the "$usr_age" variable has anything that is not a number, it warns the user, but it doesn't exit the script. I also tried changing the last || to && but if I do so it will just exit the script even if the variable is all numbers.

*Note: the "$null" variable is just "/dev/null"*

Thank you.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/806906/1707353) might be useful.

Comment: What's the intent behind `|| exit 1`? You're telling it to run `exit 1` only if `echo` fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a grouping operator to combine the `echo` and the `exit`. `a || b` runs `b` only if `a` fails, whereas you want to run `exit` whether or not `echo` succeeds.

```
grep -q "^[0-9]*$" <<<"$usr_age" || { echo "Only use numbers in the Age field."; exit 1; }
```

By the way -- `grep`, as an external command, is quite slow to start up compared to using a shell builtin. Consider instead bash's built-in regex support:

```
[[ $usr_age =~ ^[0-9]*$ ]] || { echo "Only use numbers in the Age field."; exit 1; }
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly now. I didn't think about grouping them. Also I didn't know about that regex operator, very cool!

Comment: BTW, the reason to use `grep -q` instead of `grep >/dev/null` is that `-q` is faster -- it can exit the moment it sees a match, instead of needing to read to the end of input (and write matches to `/dev/null` -- which is fast compared to writing to actual disk, but it's still a switch between userland and kernelspace for every write, so they're not completely free). That's not a big difference for a one-line input, of course, but it's a good habit to be in for when you're searching in a larger file.