# Bash script using getopts to store strings as an array

Tags: bash, getopts

I am working on a Bash script that needs to take zero to multiple strings as an input but I am unsure how to do this because of the lack of a flag before the list.

The script usage:

```
script [ list ] [ -t <secs> ] [ -n <count> ]
```

The list takes zero, one, or multiple strings as input. When a space is encountered, that acts as the break between the strings in a case of two or more. These strings will eventually be input for a `grep` command, so my idea is to save them in an array of some kind. I currently have the `-t` and `-n` working correctly. I have tried looking up examples but have been unable to find anything that is similar to what I want to do. My other concern is how to ignore string input after a flag is set so no other strings are accepted.

My current script:

```
while getopts :t:n: arg; do
  case ${arg} in
    t)
      seconds=${OPTARG}
      if ! [[ $seconds =~ ^[1-9][0-9]*$ ]] ; then
        exit
      fi
      ;;
    n)
      count=${OPTARG}
      if ! [[ $count =~ ^[1-9][0-9]*$ ]] ; then
        exit
      fi
      ;;
    :)
      echo "$0: Must supply an argument to -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit
      ;;
    ?)
      echo "Invalid option: -${OPTARG}"
      exit
      ;;
  esac
done
```

**Edit:** <strike>This is for a homework assignment and am unsure if the order of arguments can change</strike>

**Edit 2:** Options can be in any order

Comment: Can we switch the order of arguments suc as: `script [ -t <secs> ] [ -n <count> ] [ list ]`?

Comment: @tshiono I should of stated this in the post (I will update it). This is for a homework assignment so no, the order cannot be changed.

Comment: how do you distinguish between `-t 5` being the optional `[ -t <secs> ]` versus `[ list ]` ?

Comment: What is `grep` supposed to do when `[ list ]` is zero strings?

Comment: @jhnc I have a default value set for seconds and count if the `-t` or `-n` flags are not met. I have been unable to figure out how to take a string in the first place. So I do not believe I can fully answer your question. 

`grep` is combined with a `ps` command to list certain processes.

Comment: what I mean is that `script -t 5` is ambiguous. `-t 5` could be either a 2-string `list`, or a 0-string `list` followed by a `-t <secs>`

Comment: and `grep` requires a pattern to search for, so your program needs to handle the case that zero patterns are supplied (technically, `grep ''` should work - it matches everything - but you need to decide if that is the desired behaviour)

Comment: The standard when mixing options and raw arguments is to set the options first with getopt or getopts, then optionally stop at -- for end of option switch, and process any variable arguments afterward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# parse the arguments before getopts
for i in "$@"; do
    if [[ $i = "-"* ]]; then
        break
    else                # append the arguments to "list" as long as it does not start with "-"
        list+=("$1")
        shift
    fi
done

while getopts :t:n: arg; do
    : your "case" code here
done

# see if the variables are properly assigned
echo "seconds=$seconds" "count=$count"
echo "list=${list[@]}"
```

Comment: From the quick tests I have done, it appears to work for my use case! I really apriciate the help. To make sure I understand what it is doing: it cheks for strings, once a `-` is met, it goes to my case code and operates

Comment: Thank you for the prompt feedback. Your understanding commented above is absolutely correct. If you have any questions in your further testing, please let me know. Cheers.

Comment: As `$@` is *defaults argumentts*, `for varname in "$@" ;do`  could be written `for varname ; do`.  (`in "$@"` in implicit).

Comment: Why the break? You need continue.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

# Set defaults
count=10
seconds=20

args=( "$@" )
end_idx=$(($#-1))

# Check for '-n' option at the end
if [[ end_idx -gt 0 && ${args[end_idx-1]} == -n ]]; then
    count=${args[end_idx]}
    end_idx=$((end_idx-2))
fi

# Check for '-t' option at the (possibly new) end
if [[ end_idx -gt 0 && ${args[end_idx-1]} == -t ]]; then
    seconds=${args[end_idx]}
    end_idx=$((end_idx-2))
fi

# Take remaining arguments up to the (possibly new) end as the list of strings
strings=( "${args[@]:0:end_idx+1}" )

declare -p strings seconds count
```

- The basic idea is to process the arguments right-to-left instead of left-to-right.
- The code assumes that the only acceptable order of arguments is the one given in the question.  In particular, it assumes that the `-t` and `-n` options must be at the end if they are present, and they must be in that order if both are present.
- It makes no attempt to handle option arguments combined with options (e.g. `-t5` instead of `-t 5`).  That could be done fairly easily if required.
- It's OK for strings in the list to begin with `-`.

Comment: I have tested this one as well and it works with my test cases. This one is more strict on the order, so it may be better depending on what answer I recieve for my professor on if order matters. The homework does not state explicitly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

#### My *shorter* version

Some remarks:

- Instead of loop over all argument******, then *`break`* if argument begin by `-`, I simply use a `while` loop.
- From [How do I test if a variable is a number in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61835747/1765658), added  efficient `is_int` test function
- As any output (`echo`) done in `while getopts ...` loop would be an error, redirection do *`STDERR`* (`>&2`) could be addressed to the whole loop instead of repeated on each `echo` line.
- ****** Note doing a loop over all argument could be written `for varname ;do`. as `$@` stand for *default arguments*, `in "$@"` are implicit in `for` loop.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

is_int() { case ${1#[-+]} in
               '' | *[!0-9]* ) echo "Argument '$1' is not a number"; exit 3;;
           esac ;}

while [[ ${1%%-*} ]];do
    args+=("$1")
    shift
done

while getopts :t:n: arg; do
    case ${arg} in
        t ) is_int "${OPTARG}" ; seconds=${OPTARG} ;;
        n ) is_int "${OPTARG}" ; count=${OPTARG} ;;
        : ) echo "$0: Must supply an argument to -$OPTARG" ; exit 2;;
        ? ) echo "Invalid option: -${OPTARG}" ; exit 1;;
    esac
done >&2

declare -p seconds count args
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard practice is to place option arguments before any non-option arguments or variable arguments.

`getopts` natively recognizes `--` as the end of option switches delimiter.
If you need to pass arguments that starts with a dash `-`, you use the `--` delimiter, so `getopts` stops trying to intercept option arguments.

Here is an implementation:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# SYNOPSIS
#   script [-t<secs>] [-n<count>] [string]...

# Counter of option arguments
declare -i opt_arg_count=0

while getopts :t:n: arg; do
  case ${arg} in
    t)
      seconds=${OPTARG}
      if ! [[ $seconds =~ ^[1-9][0-9]*$ ]] ; then
        exit
      fi
      opt_arg_count+=1
      ;;
    n)
      count=${OPTARG}
      if ! [[ $count =~ ^[1-9][0-9]*$ ]] ; then
        exit 1
      fi
      opt_arg_count+=1
      ;;
    ?)
      printf 'Invalid option: -%s\n' "${OPTARG}" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done

shift "$opt_arg_count" # Skip all option arguments

[[ "$1" == -- ]] && shift # Skip option argument delimiter if any

# Variable arguments strings are all remaining arguments
strings=("$@")

declare -p count seconds strings
```

Example usages

With strings not starting with a dash:

```
$ ./script -t45 -n10  foo bar baz qux
declare -- count="10"
declare -- seconds="45"
declare -a strings=([0]="foo" [1]="bar" [2]="baz" [3]="qux")
```

With string starting with a dash, need `--` delimiter:

```
$ ./script -t45 -n10 -- '-dashed string'  foo bar baz qux
declare -- count="10"
declare -- seconds="45"
declare -a strings=([0]="-dashed string" [1]="foo" [2]="bar" [3]="baz" [4]="qux")
```

Comment: What about `find` where options are after paths and arguments order are significants!