# How to extract numerical value from array of string in bash

Tags: javascript, json, linux, bash, scripting

If array = `["stack","overflow","5","6","question","9"]`

I want to make another array to store all numerical values like:
`new_arr = [5,6,9] in bash`.

Comment: From where comes this array please ?

Comment: if array of string is given how can we extract integer from it using bash

Comment: There are no commas or square brackets in bash array. Can you show actual code?

Comment: what you've provided in the question is invalid `bash` ... invalid assigment statement (no spaces on either side of `=`) ... invalid array syntax (no brackets, no commas); if your initial array is named `array` then please update the question to show the complete output from `typeset -p array`

Comment: please update the question to show the (`bash`) code you've tried so far and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: @KAVITASINGH Do you have any plan of updating your question to show the real code with the array of strings?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do in `bash`:

```bash
# declare original array
arr=("stack" "overflow" "5" "6" "question" "9")

# remove all elements that have at least one non-digit character
narr=(${arr[@]//*[!0-9]*})

# check content of narr
declare -p narr
```

**Output:**

```bash
declare -a narr='([0]="5" [1]="6" [2]="9")'
```

Comment: This is not the input OP asked

Answer (score 1):

In pure bash with comments inline:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# the initial array
array=( "stack" "overflow" "5" "6" "question" "9" )

# declare the final array
declare -a new_arr

# loop over the original values
for val in "${array[@]}"
do
    # use regex to filter out those with only digits
    if [[ $val =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]];
    then
        # and append them to new_arr
        new_arr+=($val)
    fi
done

# print the result
for val in "${new_arr[@]}"
do
    echo "$val"
done
```

---

If `array` is a scalar

```bash
array='["stack","overflow","5","6","question","9"]'
```

you should use a parser. [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is useful for generic stream editing and [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) is a parser specifically made to deal with JSON data.

Here `jq` used to select only those values that contain at least 1 character and where all characters must be numbers using the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) `^[0-9]+$`:

```bash
readarray -t new_arr < <(echo "$array" | jq -r '.[] | select(test("^[0-9]+$"))')
```

Comment: This is not the user input

Comment: @GillesQuenot I'm sorry, but I don't understand. Doesn't the array I created contain the same elements as OP showed? Edit: Aha, you mean OP misrepresented it as a scalar?

Comment: @GillesQuenot Fair enough. :-) I see that question has already been raised under the question. If the input is indeed what OP shown and just not a mistake, I'll amend my answer.

Comment: @GillesQuenot It seems OP abandoned this without clarifying it further, but I added a `jq` version to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With a for loop you will be able to go through your array and then, get inspiration with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash) to determine if your iterator's value is a number or a string.

In case of a numerical value, just append it to another array.

Comment: This should belongs as a comment

Comment: I think this is borderline. Technically it can work as an answer to the question "_How to extract numerical value from array of string in bash_" because it explains what needs to be done in words, but I really doubt it will be helpful to the asker without following the link. I assume the asker wanted code.

Comment: Rules are clear on so & co, you can provide links if you copy code. Links could be dead...

Answer (score -1):

With [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs):

The proper tool for your proper input:

```
array = ["stack","overflow","5","6","question","9"]
```

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=( $(
    node<<EOF
    new_arr = ["stack","overflow","5","6","question","9"]
    .filter(e => e.match(/^\d+$/));
    new_arr.forEach(e => console.log(e))
EOF
)) 
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" # plain bash array
```

### Online test

```js
new_arr = ["stack","overflow","5","6","question","9"]
.filter(e => e.match(/^\d+$/));
new_arr.forEach(e => console.log(e))
```

Comment: how can we do in bash ???

Comment: This is now with `bash` or other shell ;)

Comment: This is not in bash, your solution is still based on `nodejs`....

Comment: Yes, and the shell is an _orchestrator_ to use third party tools, like here: `nodejs`. Same for `perl`, `sed`, `awk`, these are binary that `bash` can call