# Using nested for loop Write a bash script to validate charectors and data type in any two field records are matching or not

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Sample data:

```
Header | <Transaction_ID> | <Item_ Name> |<Item_Type> | <Customer_ID> | <Type_of_Transaction> | <Payment_Method>|Amount

Data |1001 |Samsung |Handset |R2R003 |Online |Credit Card |100|

Data | 1004|LG |TV | R2R042| Online | Debit card|150.24|

Trailer | 2
```

Here number of fields in header is 7.We need to check whether the charectors in any two field records are matching or not and also we need to check whether the data type of fields matching with it's record.

Requirement:

Need to use nested for loop to perform validation of any two or three field records.

I tried this code below but it works fine for one field records.

```bash
!# /bin/bash 

now=`date +"%d_%m_%y" ` 

file=transaction${now}.dat.gz 

#header_fieldc is a parameter which has each header fields in new line 

header_fieldc=`zcat $file | head -1|tr "|" "\n" ` 

a=( $header_fieldc) 

for (( i=0; i<=${#a[@]}; i++ ));do 
 
  echo "${a[i]}" 
 
  if [ $i == 0 ];then 
  
    i=`expr $i + 1 ` 
    rec_fieldc=`zcat $file |sed'1d;$d' 
    |cut -d\| -f $i `
  
  fi 
  #rec_fieldc parameter contains records of ith header field .
 
  b=( $rec_fieldc )
 
   for (( j=0; j<=${#b[@]}; j++ ));do 
         
          echo "${b[j]}" 
         
          var=`echo "${b[j]}" ` 
         
          if [[ "${var}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]];then 
               echo " ${b[j]} valid" 
        
           else 
                 echo "invalid character precent in ${a[j]} field" >exception.txt 
                 exit 0 
           fi 
   done
 
done
```

Output:

```
<TransactionID> 

1001 is a valid record 

1004 is a valid record
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE: do not forget that if statements use `==` to compare and not `=` otherwise I think your code might work if you correct this.**

I replicated the setup like so. I added a few lines that have more/fewer fields for the demo. Contents of sample_data.txt:

```
Header | <Transaction ID> | <Item Name> |<Item Type> | <Customer ID> | <Type of Transaction> | <Payment Method>| Amount
Data |1001 |Samsung |Handset |R2R003 |Online |Credit Card |100|
Data |1001 |Samsung |Handset |R2R003 |Online |extra |Credit Card |100|
Data |1001 |Samsung |Online |Credit Card |100|
Data | 1004|LG |TV | R2R042| Online | Debit card|150.24|
Data |1001 |Samsung |Handset |R2R003 |Online |extra |Credit Card |100|
Trailer | 2
```

Here is the script test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
header_field_count=$(cat sample_data.txt | awk -F '|' '{print NF}' |head -1)
echo 'header_field_count:' $header_field_count
number_of_lines=$(wc -l < sample_data.txt)
echo 'number of lines to process in file:' $number_of_lines
let current_line=2 #skip 1st line because that is header
data_field_count_array=($(cat sample_data.txt | awk -F '|' '{print NF -1}')) # note NF -1 because these lines have an extra separator at the end
while [ $current_line -lt $number_of_lines ]; do
  echo 'line:' $current_line 'has' ${data_field_count_array[$current_line-1]} 'fields' #bash arrays are zero indexed therefore the -1 (line 1 is index 0)
  if [[ ${data_field_count_array[$current_line-1]} == $header_field_count ]]; then
    echo 'EQUAL to the Header'
  else
    echo 'NOT EQUAL to the Header'
  fi
  let current_line+=1
done
# this will print any duplicate lines in the sample data
echo -n 'duplicate lines: '
echo $(sort sample_data.txt  | uniq -d)
```

when running this is the output:

```
header_field_count: 8
number of lines to process in file: 6
line: 2 has 8 fields
EQUAL to the Header
line: 3 has 9 fields
NOT EQUAL to the Header
line: 4 has 6 fields
NOT EQUAL to the Header
line: 5 has 8 fields
EQUAL to the Header
duplicate lines: Data |1001 |Samsung |Handset |R2R003 |Online |extra |Credit Card |100|
```

it will work with any number of data lines

You can do more research and add more validation example to check if fields are valid numbers. See: [How do I test if a variable is a number in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash)

Example validation of character types:
you can play with this script by calling it:

`./script.sh Test this string for me` will pass the string check

`./script.sh -187.8` will pass the number check

```
#!/bin/bash
#regex example
echo 'testing string:"'$@'"'
re='^[0-9 -.]'     #number digits and negative or decimal allowed
if ! [[ $@ =~ $re ]]; then #compare input with the allowed character regex
  echo 'not a decimal or negative number'
fi
re='^[a-z ,]'     #lower case letters and SPACE COMA allowed
if ! [[ $@ =~ $re ]]; then
  echo 'not a lowercase string with SPACE or COMA'
fi
re='^[a-zA-Z ,.;]' #lower and uppercase letters and SPACE COMA DOT SEMICOLON allowed
if ! [[ $@ =~ $re ]]; then
  echo 'not a text string'
fi
```

You can add whatever characters like `@` into the brackets if you want to check for e-mails or something.

This is the last edit (the question is too far into details)

```
#!/bin/bash
header_field_count=$(cat sample_data.txt | awk -F '|' '{print NF}' |head -1)
echo 'header_field_count:' $header_field_count
number_of_lines=$(wc -l < sample_data.txt)
echo 'number of lines to process in file:' $number_of_lines
let current_line=2 #skip 1st line because that is header
data_field_count_array=($(cat sample_data.txt | awk -F '|' '{print NF -1}')) # note NF -1 because these lines have an extra separator at the end
while [ $current_line -lt $number_of_lines ]; do
  echo 'line:' $current_line 'has' ${data_field_count_array[$current_line-1]} 'fields' #bash arrays are zero indexed therefore the -1 (line 1 is index 0)
  if [[ ${data_field_count_array[$current_line-1]} == $header_field_count ]]; then
    echo 'EQUAL to the Header'
  else
    echo 'NOT EQUAL to the Header'
  fi
  let current_line+=1
done
fieldstocheck=("Amount" "<Item Name>")  #name of fields to check; array may be expanded
fieldtypecheck=("num" "string")     #we specify the check requirements (customer ID needs to be a number and so on)
#find which field index in each row corresponds to fieldstocheck
for i in $(seq 1 1 $header_field_count) ; do
  field=$(cat sample_data.txt | head -1 | awk -F '|' '{print $'$i'}')
  let finalindex=${#fieldstocheck[@]}-1
  for j in $(seq 0 1 $finalindex); do
    if [[ "$field" =~ "${fieldstocheck[j]}" ]]; then
      echo $field '==' ${fieldstocheck[j]} 'at index:' $i
      fieldstocheck[j]=$i
    fi
  done
done

#check the column entries if they are valid
let finalindex=${#fieldstocheck[@]}-1
for i in $(seq 0 1 $finalindex); do
  echo $i
  echo 'column' "${fieldstocheck[$i]}" 'needs to be a' "${fieldtypecheck[$i]}"
  fieldlist=("$(cat sample_data.txt | awk -F '|' '{print $'${fieldstocheck[$i]}'}')")
  for j in ${fieldlist[@]}; do
    case "${fieldtypecheck[$i]}" in
      num)
        re='^[0-9 -.]'     #number digits and negative or decimal allowed
        if [[ "$j" =~ $re ]]; then
          echo 'OK number' $j
        else
          echo 'ERROR not a decimal or negative number' $j
        fi
      ;;
      string)
        re='^[a-zA-Z ,.;]' #lower and uppercase letters and SPACE COMA DOT SEMICOLON allowed
        if [[ "$j" =~ $re ]]; then
          echo 'OK string' $j
        else
          echo 'ERROR not a string' $j
        fi
      ;;
      *)
        echo 'not valid variable type'
      ;;
    esac
  done
done
```

Comment: Ur code work fine only to count feilds in single record but i want to compare feild of header with field count of each data_record for that we we need to use for loop as i tryed above but am getting error for the code mentioned above.

Comment: What is this line trying to do? `if [ "${data_fields}" -eq "${i}" ]` you are checking a string against a number...

Comment: there is also an error `cat sampl_data.txt` should be `cat sample_data.txt`

Comment: I created a complete script, please check if this is what you need.

Comment: Could you tell me how to check the characters are valid or not for each field.

Comment: Please edit your question if you want a more specific answer. I don't know what "characters" and "valid" you are talking about if you don't specify that in your question. Otherwise mark the answer correct with the check mark if it works.

Comment: I have edited the question according to my request plz go through it once

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to check for identical lines. (aka if 2 data lines are the same). There is no way to test what is valid and what is invalid. It is not possible to check for example `item name` unless you have a list of what valid item names to check against. The best I can do is check for numbers and strings, `value` and `transaction ID` must be a number.

Comment: I updated the answer, please mark it correct if it helped. Do some research and see what else you could add to do more validation. I can't write the entire thing for you.

Comment: I have marked ur answer But Gerge I think you didn't understood the second question which I have updated u r telling validation of records and number of fields.But am talking about the charectors, suppose there is email id column in emp table their only @ and dot symbols are valid and all other special characters are invalid this is what I need check for atleast any two fields.

Comment: OK, that is a lot more clear. I added examples to do that in the answer according to the link I gave.

Comment: Hello Gerge I Have updated the question once again and i have used ur logic to validate the record but it is not working for more fields could you solve this problem.