# Bash script to find and return files in directory

Tags: bash

I am a non-programmer experimenting more than anything by writing a commandline based system to write a blog.

I have the following as part of a longer script:

```bash
# Find & list out files
filefind (){
files=( */*.md )
  PS3="$MSG" ;
  select file in "${files[@]}"; do
    if [[ $REPLY == "0" ]]; then echo 'Bye!' >&2 ; exit
    elif [[ -z $file ]]; then echo 'Invalid choice, try again' >&2
    else break 
    fi
  done
}
```

I would like to `echo " No Files found. Enter 0 to exit"` if the folder is empty. I realise I would need another *elif* line to do this.

When I run this, as is, I always get a return of:

```
{ ~/Code/newblog } $ ./blog pp
1) /.md
Choose file to Publish, or 0 to exit:
```

Ideally I'd like only the message with exit option, but would also like to understand why the **/.md** is returned. Apologies if this is answered elsewhere, hard to know what to look for if you don't know what to look for..! Happy to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### My two cents:

As mostly I try to not use `shopt` in my scripts, I would like to present the way I use for this:

First, in every script I write, I use a `die` function:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

progName=${0##*/}
die() {
    echo "ERROR $progName: $*" >&2
    exit 1
}
```

Then for searching for files, I use:

```bash
pattern='*/*.md'
files=($pattern)

[[ -e ${files[0]} ]] || die "No files matching '$pattern' found."
```

- `test -e $variable` check for *existance* of entry (file, dir, block, link, character, pipe, socket, or else...).

```bash
[[ -f ${files[0]} ]] || die "No files matching '$pattern' found."
```

Will check that first *entry* is a *file*.

#### Using `shopt` anyway, but playing with `extglob`:

The `extglob` permit a lot of things! One of my favorite is *negation* pattern.

For sample, if you may backup your file by adding `bak` at begin or end of filename, but keeping extention: `bak_file-1234.md` or `file-1234_bak.md`, you could use on of them:

```bash
 shopt -s extglob
 pattern='*/!(bak_*).md'       # Avoid filename that begin by bak_
 pattern='*/!(*_bak).md'       # Avoid filename that end by _bak
 pattern='*/!(*_bak|bak_*).md' # Avoid both.
```

#### Full script sample

```bash
#!/bin/bash

progName=${0##*/}
die() { echo "ERROR $progName: $*" >&2; exit 1 ;}

shopt -s extglob
pattern='*/!(*_bak).md'
files=($pattern)
[[ -e ${files[0]} ]] || die "No files matching '$pattern' found."

for i in "${!files[@]}"; do
    file=${files[i]}
    printf 'Processing file %d/%d: \47%s\47.\n' $i ${#files[@]} "$file"
    : Doing something with "$file"...
done
```

Comment: I've since this morning changed the script, removed ```shopt``` and replaced using your snippet above ```if [[ ! -e ${files[0]} ]]; then echo No files....```.

I'm trying these different approaches to see how they affect or otherwise what I am doing, but also in an attempt to understand the basics of what is going on.  My project is purely **hobby** level, and I'm a sexagenarian and have no interest other than to solve this or that problem. Coding keeps my brain active.

Comment: If you're interested in trying different approaches on many concepts, you may be intersted by [isnum test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61835747/1765658) and some other of my posts: [search for *comparison* in F-Hauri's posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1765658+comparison). Happy new year!

Comment: I'm sure I will delve a little deeper into some aspects. Today I managed to extract items marked in YAML frontmatter as **tags**, format each tag save a temporary copy and then inject into my html markup at a specified place.  A bit of **awk** and some more **sed**.

I'm sure what I have could be better, but it works. next is to make those *tags* live and collate articles/html pages with the same tag.

Happy New Year to you too.

Answer (score 2):

If you do a

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

a pattern such as `*/*.md` does not expand to anything and is removed, if there are no matching entries. Hence if you have then

```
files=( */*.md )
```

the array will be empty if there are no md files, and you can test this condition by i.e.

```
if (( ${#files[@]} == 0 ))
then
  echo No files found.
  ...
fi
```

Without setting *nullglob*, `*/*.md` would simply be left unexpanded.

Comment: Without `nullglob`, you could: `if [[ ! -e ${files[0]} ]]; then echo No files...`.

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub : Not really. Imagine that there *is* exactly one file  named `*.md`. You could not distinguish it from the _no file_ case.

Comment: (Already tried!!)  There is no need to *distinguish*! Either `[[ -e $file ]]` exist or not! (Aka is an file system entry or is left unexpanded)

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub : You are right, and more elegant indeed since you don't need _nullglob_.

Answer (score 0):

I now have this which seems to be working as expected. As I make progress on my programme I will no doubt be doing more reading as I solve problems along the way. `shopt -s nullglob` is on the reading list, after a brief visit to the BASH Reference Manual.

Thank you.

```
filefind() {
  shopt -s nullglob
  files=( */*.md )
  PS3="$MSG" ;
  if (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )); then
    echo "No Files found." >&2; exit 
  fi
  select file in "${files[@]}"; do
    if [[ $REPLY == "0" ]]; then echo 'Bye!' >&2;  exit
    elif [[ -z $file ]]; then echo 'Invalid choice, try again' >&2
    else break
    fi
  done
}
```

Comment: Instead of loop over `select`, you may be interested by something like  `sellist=();for i in ${!files[@]};do sellist+=($i ${files[i]} off);done;choice=($(dialog --checklist 'Choose a file' 22 78 18 "${sellist[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty));for i in ${choice[@]};do echo Proceed ${files[i]};done`.

Comment: You may use `whiptail` or `gdialog`  instead of `dialog`, see [How do I prompt for Yes/No/Cancel input in a Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27875395/1765658)

Answer (score -1):

```
# Find & list out files
filefind() {
  files=( */*.md )
  if [ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "No Files found. Enter 0 to exit" >&2
    exit 1
  fi

  PS3="$MSG" ;
  select file in "${files[@]}"; do
    if [[ $REPLY == "0" ]]; then
      echo 'Bye!' >&2
      exit
    elif [[ -z $file ]]; then
      echo 'Invalid choice, try again' >&2
    else
      break
    fi
  done
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).